# What exactly does git's "rebase --preserve-merges" do (and why?)

Tags: git, git-rebase

Git's [documentation for the `rebase` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) is quite brief:

```
--preserve-merges
    Instead of ignoring merges, try to recreate them.

This uses the --interactive machinery internally, but combining it
with the --interactive option explicitly is generally not a good idea
unless you know what you are doing (see BUGS below).
```

So what actually happens when you use `--preserve-merges`? How does it differ from the default behavior (without that flag)? What does it mean to "recreate" a merge, etc.

Comment: Warning: starting with Git 2.18 (Q2 2018, 5 years later), `git --rebase-merges` will ultimately replace the old `git --preserve-merges`. See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50555740/6309)

Comment: Fatal: from Git 2.35.0 (Q1 2022) `rebase-merges` was removed and will result in a number of different `fatal:` messages, depending on how you chance upon the option. There are edge cases.  Visual Studio has yet to notice, particularly for the `git pull` config options

Comment: @Philip Presumably you meant `--preserve-merges` has been removed?

Comment: Y’all could just edit the question and put these warnings at the top. Then the original question below for its historical value. :·)

Comment: @ak2 Yes. It can be easy to confuse the two 'rebase' options. One of those 'should have checked the manual' moments. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 508):

As with a normal git rebase, git with `--preserve-merges` first identifies a list of commits made in one part of the commit graph, and then replays those commits on top of another part. The differences with `--preserve-merges` concern which commits are selected for replay and how that replaying works for merge commits.

To be more explicit about the main differences between normal and merge-preserving rebase:

- Merge-preserving rebase is willing to replay (some) merge commits, whereas normal rebase completely ignores merge commits.
- Because it's willing to replay merge commits, merge-preserving rebase has to define what it *means* to replay a merge commit, and deal with some extra wrinkles

  - The most interesting part, conceptually, is perhaps in picking what the new commit's merge parents should be.
  - Replaying merge commits also require explicitly checking out particular commits (`git checkout <desired first parent>`), whereas normal rebase doesn't have to worry about that.
- Merge-preserving rebase considers a shallower set of commits for replay:

  - In particular, it will only consider replaying commits made since the most recent merge base(s) -- i.e. the *most recent* time the two branches diverged --, whereas normal rebase might replay commits going back to the *first* time the two branches diverged.
  - To be provisional and unclear, I believe this is ultimately a means to screen out replaying "old commits" that have already been "incorporated into" a merge commit.

First I will try to describe "sufficiently exactly" what rebase `--preserve-merges` does, and then there will be some examples. One can of course start with the examples, if that seems more useful.

**The Algorithm in "Brief"**

If you want to really get into the weeds, download the git source and explore the file `git-rebase--interactive.sh`. (Rebase is not part of Git's C core, but rather is written in bash. And, behind the scenes, it shares code with "interactive rebase".)

But here I will sketch what I think is the essence of it. In order to reduce the number of things to think about, I have taken a few liberties. (e.g. I don't try to capture with 100% accuracy the precise order in which computations take place, and ignore some less central-seeming topics, e.g. what to do about commits that have already been cherry-picked between branches).

First, note that a non-merge-preserving rebase is rather simple. It's more or less:

```
Find all commits on B but not on A ("git log A..B")
Reset B to A ("git reset --hard A") 
Replay all those commits onto B one at a time in order.
```

Rebase `--preserve-merges` is comparatively complicated. Here's as simple as I've been able to make it without losing things that seem pretty important:

```
Find the commits to replay:
  First find the merge-base(s) of A and B (i.e. the most recent common ancestor(s))
    This (these) merge base(s) will serve as a root/boundary for the rebase.
    In particular, we'll take its (their) descendants and replay them on top of new parents
  Now we can define C, the set of commits to replay. In particular, it's those commits:
    1) reachable from B but not A (as in a normal rebase), and ALSO
    2) descendants of the merge base(s)
  If we ignore cherry-picks and other cleverness preserve-merges does, it's more or less:
    git log A..B --not $(git merge-base --all A B)
Replay the commits:
  Create a branch B_new, on which to replay our commits.
  Switch to B_new (i.e. "git checkout B_new")
  Proceeding parents-before-children (--topo-order), replay each commit c in C on top of B_new:
    If it's a non-merge commit, cherry-pick as usual (i.e. "git cherry-pick c")
    Otherwise it's a merge commit, and we'll construct an "equivalent" merge commit c':
      To create a merge commit, its parents must exist and we must know what they are.
      So first, figure out which parents to use for c', by reference to the parents of c:
        For each parent p_i in parents_of(c):
          If p_i is one of the merge bases mentioned above:
            # p_i is one of the "boundary commits" that we no longer want to use as parents
            For the new commit's ith parent (p_i'), use the HEAD of B_new.
          Else if p_i is one of the commits being rewritten (i.e. if p_i is in R):
            # Note: Because we're moving parents-before-children, a rewritten version
            # of p_i must already exist. So reuse it:
            For the new commit's ith parent (p_i'), use the rewritten version of p_i.
          Otherwise:
            # p_i is one of the commits that's *not* slated for rewrite. So don't rewrite it
            For the new commit's ith parent (p_i'), use p_i, i.e. the old commit's ith parent.
      Second, actually create the new commit c':
        Go to p_1'. (i.e. "git checkout p_1'", p_1' being the "first parent" we want for our new commit)
        Merge in the other parent(s):
          For a typical two-parent merge, it's just "git merge p_2'".
          For an octopus merge, it's "git merge p_2' p_3' p_4' ...".
        Switch (i.e. "git reset") B_new to the current commit (i.e. HEAD), if it's not already there
  Change the label B to apply to this new branch, rather than the old one. (i.e. "git reset --hard B")
```

Rebase with an `--onto C` argument should be very similar. Just instead of starting commit playback at the HEAD of B, you start commit playback at the HEAD of C instead. (And use C_new instead of B_new.)

**Example 1**

For example, take commit graph

```
  B---C <-- master
 /                     
A-------D------E----m----H <-- topic
         \         /
          F-------G
```

m is a merge commit with parents E and G.

Suppose we rebased topic (H) on top of master (C) using a normal, non-merge-preserving
rebase. (For example, *checkout topic; rebase master*.) In that case, git would select
the following commits for replay:

- pick D
- pick E
- pick F
- pick G
- pick H

and then update the commit graph like so:

```
  B---C <-- master
 /     \                
A       D'---E'---F'---G'---H' <-- topic
```

(D' is the replayed equivalent of D, etc..)

Note that merge commit m is not selected for replay.

If we instead did a `--preserve-merges` rebase of H on top of C. (For example, *checkout topic; rebase --preserve-merges master*.) In this new case, git would select the following commits for replay:

- pick D
- pick E
- pick F (onto D' in the 'subtopic' branch)
- pick G (onto F' in the 'subtopic' branch)
- pick Merge branch 'subtopic' into topic
- pick H

Now m *was* chosen for replay. Also note that merge parents E and G were
picked for inclusion before merge commit m.

Here is the resulting commit graph:

```
 B---C <-- master
/     \                
A      D'-----E'----m'----H' <-- topic
        \          / 
         F'-------G'
```

Again, D' is a cherry-picked (i.e. recreated) version of D. Same for E', etc.. Every commit not on master has been replayed. Both E and G (the merge parents of m) have been recreated as E' and G' to serve as the parents of m' (after rebase, the tree history still remains the same).

**Example 2**

Unlike with normal rebase, merge-preserving rebase can create multiple
children of the upstream head.

For example, consider:

```
  B---C <-- master
 /                     
A-------D------E---m----H <-- topic
 \                 |
  ------- F-----G--/
```

If we rebase H (topic) on top of C (master), then the commits chosen for rebase are:

- pick D
- pick E
- pick F
- pick G
- pick m
- pick H

And the result is like so:

```
  B---C  <-- master
 /    | \                
A     |  D'----E'---m'----H' <-- topic
       \            |
         F'----G'---/
```

**Example 3**

In the above examples, both the merge commit and its two parents are replayed commits, rather than the original parents that the original merge commit have. However, in other rebases a replayed merge commit can end up with parents that were already in the commit graph before the merge.

For example, consider:

```
  B--C---D <-- master
 /    \                
A---E--m------F <-- topic
```

If we rebase topic onto master (preserving merges), then the commits to replay will be

- pick merge commit m
- pick F

The rewritten commit graph will look like so:

```
                     B--C--D <-- master
                    /       \             
                   A-----E---m'--F'; <-- topic
```

Here replayed merge commit m' gets parents that pre-existed in the commit graph, namely D (the HEAD of master) and E (one of the parents of the original merge commit m).

**Example 4**

Merge-preserving rebase can get confused in certain "empty commit" cases. At least this is true only some older versions of git (e.g. 1.7.8.)

Take this commit graph:

```
                   A--------B-----C-----m2---D <-- master
                    \        \         /
                      E--- F--\--G----/
                            \  \
                             ---m1--H <--topic
```

Note that both commit m1 and m2 should have incorporated all the changes from B and F.

If we try to do `git rebase --preserve-merges` of H (topic) onto D (master), then the following commits are chosen for replay:

- pick m1
- pick H

Note that the changes (B, F) united in m1 should already be incorporated into D. (Those changes should already be incorporated into m2, because m2 merges together the children of B and F.) Therefore, conceptually, replaying m1 on top of D should probably either be a no-op or create an empty commit (i.e. one where the diff between successive revisions is empty).

Instead, however, git may reject the attempt to replay m1 on top of D. You can get an error like so:

```
error: Commit 90caf85 is a merge but no -m option was given.
fatal: cherry-pick failed
```

It looks like one forgot to pass a flag to git, but the underlying problem is that git dislikes creating empty commits.

Comment: I've noticed that `git rebase --preserve-merges` is **much** slower than a `rebase` without `--preserve-merges`. Is that a side-effect of finding the right commits? Is there anything one can do to speed it up? (By the way…thanks for the very detailed answer!)

Comment: It sounds like you should always use --preserve-merges. Otherwise there is the potential to lose history i.e. the merge commits.

Comment: @DarVar You always loose history on a rebase, because you claim that changes where made to a different codebase than they actually where.

Comment: Example 1 looks completely logical to me, since the merge base is affected by the rebase operation. But regarding Example 2, what exactly is the benefit of doing it like that? I'm rebasing one branch and not touching the merge base. So I'd have expected it to change just the commits on that branch, i.e. m' should have E' and the original G as merge parents.

Comment: @Chronial is correct. By doing a rebase you're already saying that you're willing to blow up your current railroad track (branch history), take all the railroad ties from your track (commits), and stick them under the main railroad track. Then the feature branch simply becomes a reference to a railroad tie further down the track from the tie that master references. You already lost the history indicating that the other track ever even existed at all. Master and your feature branch are now just references to commits on the same history line.

Comment: @DarVar On the contrary, I think this highlights some of the reasons why rewriting merges is difficult to always do correctly, and thus you should organize your workflow in such a way as to never need to use `--preserve-merges`. Generally speaking, since rebasing is rewriting things, if you are applying it in such a way that things outside your local repository will be affected, then there's probably a better approach to the overall workflow. Granted, there are times you have to break things due to circumstances you can't control, though...

Comment: Is this still a "provisional answer"?

Comment: @Chronial Of course you're right, that rebasing always incorporates loosing history, but perhaps DarVar was alluding to the fact, that you not only loose history, but also changes to the code base. The conflict resolution contains information which is lost in all possible ways a rebase can be done. You always have to redo it. Is there really no way, to let git redo your conflict resolution? Why can't git cherry-pick the merge commit?

Comment: Related to this question: To merge a repo onto another one keeping commit dates and history see: http://axiac.ro/blog/2014/11/merging-git-repositories/

Comment: @AndrewGrimm removed that, as a community wiki and 200+ rep, should be fine :-)

Comment: Is there a way to force preserve for all rebase globally using git config? For git pull --rebase we can use `git config --global pull.rebase preserve`, but for classical rebase? Would this work? `git config --global branch.rebase preserve`

Comment: `--preserve-merges` is deprecated. Use `--rebase-merges` or `-r` mode, which is similar in spirit and it works faster.

Answer (score 147):

Git 2.18 (Q2 2018) will improve considerably the `--preserve-merge` option by adding a new option.

"`git rebase`" learned "`--rebase-merges`" to **transplant the whole
topology of commit graph elsewhere**.

(Note: Git 2.22, Q2 2019, actually [*deprecates* `--preserve-merge`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fa1b86e45743fd5895c33adcd3769782e608bb40), and Git 2.25, Q1 2020, [stops advertising it in the "`git rebase --help`" output](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0c51181ffb178a6581ecb471091cbd2d0c48f165))

See [commit 25cff9f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/25cff9f109afbd6d21b199a38d15911b1f0c5069), [commit 7543f6f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7543f6f4441a0ec76460a54f90ab8674fe424786), [commit 1131ec9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1131ec98189e993dcc48043c4f8e8b0128f52055), [commit 7ccdf65](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7ccdf65b63f2f4a5e751d70b9788af3c9e16b6ab), [commit 537e7d6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/537e7d61359233e95d2ca6ef6b9059afca8daa81), [commit a9be29c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a9be29c9817067128a2818a609450db6e6722ffd), [commit 8f6aed7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8f6aed71d27f33096449d28c4711d3b68159632e), [commit 1644c73](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1644c73c6d4fe35d4d3304b9c03c9586de51626f), [commit d1e8b01](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d1e8b0114bef98e8efe3f8d35430300ff9e00443), [commit 4c68e7d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4c68e7ddb59457efe9d3a141dc600feda86cbe67), [commit 9055e40](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9055e401dd63a422a4401a454ef2a0e2ef727ace), [commit cb5206e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cb5206eab196544a3b271afdff9865c103e6dbce), [commit a01c2a5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a01c2a5f59cc0f28daeab33355ae4a45490ce7e6), [commit 2f6b1d1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2f6b1d13aa730901fe328fc2d88f208ea44d4f9e), [commit bf5c057](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bf5c0571d6542d992380467c26cb7bdcab23fcb5) (25 Apr 2018) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
See [commit f431d73](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f431d73d9c9a4ee16df2f7ef66abe518c77c73d6) (25 Apr 2018) by [Stefan Beller (`stefanbeller`)](https://github.com/stefanbeller).
See [commit 2429335](https://github.com/git/git/commit/24293359ccf8a7bc2ac68a9b9bf61d6b59c873ad) (25 Apr 2018) by [Phillip Wood (`phillipwood`)](https://github.com/phillipwood).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 2c18e6a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2c18e6ae2434a6caa5b3a7256608470948e73f66), 23 May 2018)</sup>

> ### `pull`: accept `--rebase-merges` to recreate the branch topology

> Similar to the `preserve` mode simply passing the `--preserve-merges`
> option to the `rebase` command, the `merges` mode simply passes the
> `--rebase-merges` option.
>
> This will allow users to conveniently rebase non-trivial commit
> topologies when pulling new commits, without flattening them.

---

`git rebase` man page now has a [full section dedicated to rebasing history with merges](https://github.com/git/git/blob/25cff9f109afbd6d21b199a38d15911b1f0c5069/Documentation/git-rebase.txt#L806-L937).

Extract:

> There are legitimate reasons why a developer may want to
> recreate merge commits: to keep the branch structure (or "commit
> topology") when working on multiple, inter-related branches.
>
> In the following example, the developer works on a topic branch that
> refactors the way buttons are defined, and on another topic branch
> that uses that refactoring to implement a "Report a bug" button.
> The output of `git log --graph --format=%s -5` may look like this:
>
> ```
> *   Merge branch 'report-a-bug'
> |\
> | * Add the feedback button
> * | Merge branch 'refactor-button'
> |\ \
> | |/
> | * Use the Button class for all buttons
> | * Extract a generic Button class from the DownloadButton one
> ```
>
> The developer might want to rebase those commits to a newer `master`
> while keeping the branch topology, for example when the first topic
> branch is expected to be integrated into `master` much earlier than the
> second one, say, to resolve merge conflicts with changes to the
> `DownloadButton` class that made it into `master`.
>
> This rebase can be performed using the `--rebase-merges` option.

---

See [commit 1644c73](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1644c73c6d4fe35d4d3304b9c03c9586de51626f) for a small example:

> ### `rebase-helper` `--make-script`: introduce a flag to rebase merges

> The sequencer just learned new commands intended to recreate branch
> structure (**similar in spirit to `--preserve-merges`, but with a
> substantially less-broken design**).
>
> Let's allow the `rebase--helper` to generate todo lists making use of
> these commands, triggered by the new `--rebase-merges` option.
> For a commit topology like this (where the HEAD points to C):
>
> ```
> - A - B - C (HEAD)
>    \   /
>      D
> ```
>
> the generated todo list would look like this:
>
> ```
> # branch D
> pick 0123 A
> label branch-point
> pick 1234 D
> label D
>
> reset branch-point
> pick 2345 B
> merge -C 3456 D # C
> ```

---

What is the difference with `--preserve-merge`?
[Commit 8f6aed7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8f6aed71d27f33096449d28c4711d3b68159632e) explains:

> Once upon a time, this here developer thought: wouldn't it be nice if,
> say, Git for Windows' patches on top of core Git could be represented as
> a thicket of branches, and be rebased on top of core Git in order to
> maintain a cherry-pick'able set of patch series?
>
> The original attempt to answer this was: `git rebase --preserve-merges`.
>
> However, that experiment was never intended as an interactive option,
> and it only piggy-backed on `git rebase --interactive` because that
> command's implementation looked already very, very familiar: it was
> designed by the same person who designed `--preserve-merges`: yours truly.

And by "yours truly", the author refers to himself:  **[Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho)**, who is the main reason (with a few other heroes -- Hannes, Steffen, Sebastian, ...) that we have Git For Windows (even though [back in the day -- 2009 -- that was not easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1704687/6309)).
He is working at Microsoft [since Sept. 2015](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/On-a-personal-note-td7638864.html), which makes sense considering Microsoft now heavily uses Git and needs his services.
That [trend started in 2013 actually, with TFS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2013/11/13/git-for-tfs-2013/). Since then, Microsoft manages [the largest Git repository on the planet](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2017/05/24/the-largest-git-repo-on-the-planet/)! And, [since Oct. 2018, Microsoft acquired GitHub](https://blogs.microsoft.com/blog/2018/10/26/microsoft-completes-github-acquisition/).

You can see [Johannes speak in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oOMzi983Qmw&t=13s) for Git Merge 2018 in April 2018.

> Some time later, some other developer (I am looking at you, Andreas!
> ;-)) decided that it would be a good idea to allow `--preserve-merges` to
> be combined with `--interactive` (with caveats!) and the Git maintainer
> (well, the interim Git maintainer during Junio's absence, that is)
> agreed, and that is when the glamor of the `--preserve-merges` design
> started to fall apart rather quickly and unglamorously.

Here Jonathan is talking about **[Andreas Schwab](https://github.com/andreas-schwab)** from Suse.
You can see some of [their discussions back in 2012](https://public-inbox.org/git/7vwqzrmbk1.fsf@alter.siamese.dyndns.org/).

> The reason? **In `--preserve-merges` mode, the parents of a merge commit (or
> for that matter, of *any* commit) were not stated explicitly, but were
> *implied* by the commit name passed to the `pick` command**.
>
> **This made it impossible, for example, to reorder commits**.
> Not to mention to move commits between branches or, deity forbid, to split topic branches into two.
>
> Alas, these shortcomings also prevented that mode (whose original
> purpose was to serve Git for Windows' needs, with the additional hope
> that it may be useful to others, too) from serving Git for Windows'
> needs.
>
> Five years later, when it became really untenable to have one unwieldy,
> big hodge-podge patch series of partly related, partly unrelated patches
> in Git for Windows that was rebased onto core Git's tags from time to
> time (earning the undeserved wrath of the developer of the ill-fated
> `git-remote-hg` series that first obsoleted Git for Windows' competing
> approach, only to be abandoned without maintainer later) was really
> untenable, the "[Git garden shears](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/share/msysGit/shears.sh)" [were born](https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/blob/master/shears.sh): a script,
> piggy-backing on top of the interactive rebase, that would first
> determine the branch topology of the patches to be rebased, create a
> pseudo todo list for further editing, transform the result into a real
> todo list (making heavy use of the `exec` command to "implement" the
> missing todo list commands) and finally recreate the patch series on
> top of the new base commit.

(The Git garden shears script is referenced in this patch in [commit 9055e40](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9055e401dd63a422a4401a454ef2a0e2ef727ace))

> That was in 2013.
> And it took about three weeks to come up with the design and implement it as an out-of-tree script. Needless to say, the implementation needed quite a few years to stabilize, all the while the design itself proved itself sound.
>
> **With this patch, the goodness of the Git garden shears comes to `git rebase -i` itself**.
> **Passing the `--rebase-merges` option will generate
> a todo list that can be understood readily, and where it is obvious
> how to reorder commits**.
> New branches can be introduced by inserting `label` commands and calling `merge <label>`.
> **And once this mode will have become stable and universally accepted, we can deprecate the design mistake that was `--preserve-merges`**.

---

Git 2.19 (Q3 2018) improves the new `--rebase-merges` option by making it work with `--exec`.

The "`--exec`" option to "`git rebase --rebase-merges`" placed the exec
commands at wrong places, which has been corrected.

See [commit 1ace63b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1ace63bc39a339a1616477644d6c43f570716bcb) (09 Aug 2018), and [commit f0880f7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f0880f77abcbd2dbc948917e995680171eff28b0) (06 Aug 2018) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 750eb11](https://github.com/git/git/commit/750eb11d8f53feba4a797c1be1a0ad2f68f88879), 20 Aug 2018)</sup>

> ### `rebase --exec`: make it work with `--rebase-merges`

> The idea of `--exec` is to append an `exec` call after each `pick`.
>
> Since the introduction of `fixup!`/s`quash!` commits, this idea was extended
> to apply to "pick, possibly followed by a fixup/squash chain", i.e. an
> exec would not be inserted between a `pick` and any of its corresponding
> `fixup` or `squash` lines.
>
> The current implementation uses a dirty trick to achieve that: it
> assumes that there are only pick/fixup/squash commands, and then
> *inserts* the `exec` lines before any `pick` but the first, and appends
> a final one.
>
> With the todo lists generated by `git rebase --rebase-merges`, this
> simple implementation shows its problems: it produces the exact wrong
> thing when there are `label`, `reset` and `merge` commands.
>
> Let's change the implementation to do exactly what we want: **look for
> `pick` lines, skip any fixup/squash chains, and then insert the `exec`
> line**. Lather, rinse, repeat.
>
> Note: we take pains to insert *before* comment lines whenever possible,
> as empty commits are represented by commented-out pick lines (and we
> want to insert a preceding pick's exec line *before* such a line, not
> afterward).
>
> While at it, also add `exec` lines after `merge` commands, because they
> are similar in spirit to `pick` commands: they add new commits.

---

Git 2.22 (Q2 2019) fixes the usage of the refs/rewritten/ hierarchy to store a rebase intermediate states, which inherently makes the hierarchy per
worktree.

See [commit b9317d5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b9317d55a37f93c47d48f12a7b3e45a71434d0e7), [commit 90d31ff](https://github.com/git/git/commit/90d31ff5d470286a8480311384429ebee8bbc939), [commit 09e6564](https://github.com/git/git/commit/09e65645e3b092e4d93bb8513b14474c68df23d8) (07 Mar 2019) by [Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 917f2cd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/917f2cd1c2396c694ae956a1a26d9c92bf50b847), 09 Apr 2019)</sup>

> ### Make sure refs/rewritten/ is per-worktree

[a9be29c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a9be29c9817067128a2818a609450db6e6722ffd) (sequencer: make refs generated by the `label` command
worktree-local, 2018-04-25, Git 2.19) adds `refs/rewritten/` as per-worktree
reference space.
Unfortunately (my bad) there are a couple places that
need update to make sure it's really per-worktree.

> - `add_per_worktree_entries_to_dir()` is updated to make sure ref listing
>   look at per-worktree `refs/rewritten/` instead of per-repo one.
> - `common_list[]` is updated so that `git_path()` returns the correct
>   location. This includes "`rev-parse --git-path`".
>
> This mess is created by me.
> I started trying to fix it with the introduction of `refs/worktree,` where all refs will be per-worktree without special treatments.
> Unfortunate refs/rewritten came before refs/worktree so this is all we can do.

---

With Git 2.24 (Q4 2019), "`git rebase --rebase-merges`" learned to drive different merge strategies and pass strategy specific options to them.

See [commit 476998d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/476998d05bc62b9baaed240da0893ec5d80d676a) (04 Sep 2019) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
See [commit e1fac53](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e1fac531ea9f9dc710f6eeae37ea2b38dd5f9fae), [commit a63f990](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a63f990d9205d1a781aec310e44edf35e29063a2), [commit 5dcdd74](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5dcdd7409ad3b3e8d5e79871bfb9d5f4215d4a13), [commit e145d99](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e145d993478befd0db6999822aa31d422b283a3b), [commit 4e6023b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4e6023b13ae1159277a7c3053f8d074c23456812), [commit f67336d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f67336dabf8b77f1eee0341790c8fbbe5c6d81dd), [commit a9c7107](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a9c71073dace0d1ddbd12291604d191064b1ae94), [commit b8c6f24](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b8c6f24255d3224438ee8c591b7b08d665433b6b), [commit d51b771](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d51b771dc0a2ea71c44f3c4c54230f140588bacd), [commit c248d32](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c248d32cdb302812585823231cf29027db33571e), [commit 8c1e240](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8c1e24048a0a159329743a8e76251412c0f727d9), [commit 5efed0e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5efed0ecf936596377c241aa0e0bd40839bafbd5), [commit 68b54f6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/68b54f669de27c66e42793977df5b4d5a4a3fc5b), [commit 2e7bbac](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2e7bbac6be6b905773ad091bdcd7c897286c17d0), [commit 6180b20](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6180b202390a04c4c4f63453cdc75142bb2c8fae), [commit d5b581f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d5b581f228fb8b2ec3a9d6225f657dff7d28925d) (31 Jul 2019) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 917a319](https://github.com/git/git/commit/917a319ea59c130a14cff7656537ba14f593568b), 18 Sep 2019)</sup>

---

With Git 2.25 (Q1 2020), the logic used to tell worktree local and repository global refs apart is fixed, to facilitate the preserve-merge.

See [commit f45f88b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f45f88b2e483649cd063a7dc7826c03025683e56), [commit c72fc40](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c72fc40d0904cbf3199258c2f471c2351e024b1e), [commit 8a64881](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8a64881b44e03264fb0c3c26fc00a01c12cd67ff), [commit 7cb8c92](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7cb8c929d76c12750fdece2e5da75d207938d3b9), [commit e536b1f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e536b1fedf777ad8958a6f299d9d59db6299e697) (21 Oct 2019) by [SZEDER Gábor (`szeder`)](https://github.com/szeder).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit db806d7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/db806d7064ee132c2dbb3d36d26da9adb5066260), 10 Nov 2019)</sup>

> ### [`path.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f45f88b2e483649cd063a7dc7826c03025683e56): don't call the `match` function without value in `trie_find()`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: SZEDER Gábor</sup>

> 'logs/refs' is not a working tree-specific path, but since [commit b9317d55a3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b9317d55a37f93c47d48f12a7b3e45a71434d0e7) (Make sure refs/rewritten/ is per-worktree, 2019-03-07, v2.22.0-rc0) '`git rev-parse --git-path`' has been returning a bogus path if a trailing '`/`' is present:
>
> ```
> $ git -C WT/ rev-parse --git-path logs/refs --git-path logs/refs/
> /home/szeder/src/git/.git/logs/refs
> /home/szeder/src/git/.git/worktrees/WT/logs/refs/
> ```
>
> We use a `trie` data structure to efficiently decide whether a path belongs to the common dir or is working tree-specific.
>
> As it happens [b9317d55a3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b9317d55a37f93c47d48f12a7b3e45a71434d0e7) triggered a bug that is as old as the `trie` implementation itself, added in [4e09cf2acf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4e09cf2acf00c63848c365479c61d80af62eceba) ("`path`: optimize common dir checking", 2015-08-31, Git v2.7.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/297ae7151f85b677e58d6804d35e88d1375abaeb) listed in [batch #2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f5b6079871904ba5b0a8548f91545f126caf898b)).
>
> - According to the comment describing `trie_find()`, it should only call the given match function 'fn' for a "/-or-\0-terminated prefix of the key for which the trie contains a value".
>   This is not true: there are three places where trie_find() calls the match function, but one of them is missing the check for value's existence.
> - [b9317d55a3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b9317d55a37f93c47d48f12a7b3e45a71434d0e7) added two new keys to the `trie`:
> - '`logs/refs/rewritten`', and
> - '`logs/refs/worktree`', next to the already existing '`logs/refs/bisect`'.
>   This resulted in a `trie` node with the path '`logs/refs/`', which didn't exist before, and which doesn't have a value attached.
>   A query for '`logs/refs/`' finds this node and then hits that one callsite of the `match` function which doesn't check for the value's existence, and thus invokes the `match` function with `NULL` as value.
> - When the `match` function `check_common()` is invoked with a `NULL` value, it returns 0, which indicates that the queried path doesn't belong to the common directory, ultimately resulting the bogus path shown above.
>
> Add the missing condition to `trie_find()` so it will never invoke the match function with a non-existing value.
>
> `check_common()` will then no longer have to check that it got a non-NULL value, so remove that condition.
>
> I believe that there are no other paths that could cause similar bogus output.
>
> AFAICT the only other key resulting in the match function being called with a `NULL` value is '`co`' (because of the keys '`common`' and '`config`').
>
> However, as they are not in a directory that belongs to the common directory the resulting working tree-specific path is expected.

---

Make sure to use Git 2.34 (Q4 2021), to avoid a memory leak.

See [commit 6e65854](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6e658547d35515da6ba55d285d6699b7f04cb939), [commit 0c52cf8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0c52cf8e00f65bb198800a08caaadc95eaf4419a) (13 Oct 2021), and [commit e5a917f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e5a917fcf42d2e22017ae501ffdd1c2108a1431e) (07 Oct 2021) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
See [commit 9d05b45](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9d05b459c78a64ed7cc9d94f98196b731e845b49) (07 Oct 2021) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit bfa646c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bfa646c2cbad55cf652344415616eadc9e20f3c4), 25 Oct 2021)</sup>

> ### [`sequencer`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6e658547d35515da6ba55d285d6699b7f04cb939): fix a memory leak in `do_reset()`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> Fix a memory leak introduced in [9055e40](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9055e401dd63a422a4401a454ef2a0e2ef727ace) ("`sequencer`: introduce new commands to reset the revision", 2018-04-25, Git v2.18.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2c18e6ae2434a6caa5b3a7256608470948e73f66) listed in [batch #6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e144d126d74f5d2702870ca9423743102eec6fcd)), which called `setup_unpack_trees_porcelain()` without a corresponding call to `clear_unpack_trees_porcelain()`.

---

Git 2.41 (Q2 2023) streamlines `--rebase-merges` command line option handling and introduces `rebase.merges` configuration variable.

See [commit 6605fb7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6605fb70cb79776af9e20c0300dc66563a300b42), [commit 33561f5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/33561f517036dd0bcddf319a56fd3488759396e5), [commit 7e5dcec](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7e5dcec3ca4dee6d8aedd64f4dba037949f36a67) (25 Mar 2023) by [Alex Henrie (`alexhenrie`)](https://github.com/alexhenrie).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9142fce](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9142fce9b09dbc12cd99704d3ea0899efb350c39), 04 Apr 2023)</sup>

> ### [`rebase`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6605fb70cb79776af9e20c0300dc66563a300b42): add a config option for `--rebase-merges`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Alex Henrie</sup>

> The purpose of the new option is to accommodate users who would like `--rebase-merges` to be on by default and to facilitate turning on `--rebase-merges` by default without configuration in a future version of Git.
>
> Name the new option **`rebase.rebaseMerges`**, even though it is a little redundant, for consistency with the name of the command line option and to be clear when scrolling through values in the `[rebase]` section of `.gitconfig`.
>
> Support setting `rebase.rebaseMerges` to the nonspecific value "`true`" for users who don't need to or don't want to learn about the difference between rebase-cousins and no-rebase-cousins.
>
> Make `--rebase-merges` without an argument on the command line override any value of `rebase.rebaseMerges` in the configuration, for consistency with other command line flags with optional arguments that have an associated config option.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6605fb70cb79776af9e20c0300dc66563a300b42/Documentation/config/rebase.txt#L70-L79):

> ### `rebase.rebaseMerges`
>
> Whether and how to set the `--rebase-merges` option by default. Can
> be `rebase-cousins`, `no-rebase-cousins`, or a boolean. Setting to
> true or to `no-rebase-cousins` is equivalent to
> `--rebase-merges=no-rebase-cousins`, setting to `rebase-cousins` is
> equivalent to `--rebase-merges=rebase-cousins`, and setting to false is
> equivalent to `--no-rebase-merges`.
> Passing `--rebase-merges` on the
> command line, with or without an argument, overrides any
> `rebase.rebaseMerges` configuration.

`git rebase` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6605fb70cb79776af9e20c0300dc66563a300b42/Documentation/git-rebase.txt#L540-L541):

> countermand both the `rebase.rebaseMerges` config option and a previous `--rebase-merges`.

Comment: I think this should be the top answer, `--preserve-merges` doesnt actually "preserve" the merges as you want, it is very naive. This allows you to preserve the merge commits & their parent commit relationships while giving you the flexibility of an interactive rebase. This new feature is awesome & if not for this well written S.O. answer, i wouldnt have known!

Comment: @egucciar Thank you. And it is not the only feature of Git 2.18 (https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A6309+%22git+2.18%22), and Git 2.19 (https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A6309+%22git+2.19%22)

Comment: Extremely helpful if you are trying to move hunks of commits around like in this Q/A, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45059039/how-do-i-move-partial-changes-hunks-between-commits

Comment: Oh, that's really what I had looking for since a while! I had [a manual workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315285/rebasing-a-tree-a-commit-branch-and-all-its-children/45844847#45844847) for cases like that on which one should create a fictitious commit joining all the merges.

Comment: Typical Git. Dare you ask a simple question and you most probably have to learn Git's history, internal algorithms, all the messy implementation details plus you also need a major in graph theory in order to understand what is going on.

Comment: @VonC LOL! That is exactly what I often do.

Comment: Is there a way to edit the config to do --preserve-merges by default?

Comment: @JoeSchr Why preserve-merge? It is by now deprecated and no longer advertised. But anyway, check out the [`git config pull.rebase` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pullrebase): it can set either policy by default.

Comment: Sorry I got mixed up. I meant `--rebase-merges` ofc, hadn't had my coffee yet... Ty for the link.

Comment: @VonC do you know of a way to also configure it for interactive rebases? that's actually the reason why I'm looking for this?

Comment: @JoeSchr No, I don't seem to find a default config for `rebase` itself. Maybe you can specify it for that branch you want to rebase (using [`branch.<name>.rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-branchltnamegtrebase)), and then try your `rebase -i`, but I am not sure it would work.

Comment: @VonC thanks! Maybe I'm just misunderstanding the usecase for `--rebase-merge` I think I will need to look further into it

Answer (score 5):

For those ending here just because they pulled and got that message :

```
git pull
(...)
warning: git rebase --preserve-merges is deprecated. Use --rebase-merges instead.
```

Have a look into your ~/.gitconfig and /etc/gitconfig and search for this option :

```
[pull]
  rebase = preserve
```

Then head to that doc to understand and fix according to your needs : https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pullrebase

Comment: `preserve` was replaced by `merges` in v2.32.0 https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-config/2.32.0#Documentation/git-config.txt-pullrebase