# How to rebase my feature branch to development branch in git with least possible conflicts?

Tags: rebase, git-rebase, git-merge-conflict, git

I have my feature branch which has exceeded around 30 or more commits. Meanwhile in development branch few other features have been pushed from other developers. Therefore, Everytime a new feature is published on development, I am asked to:

1. Rebase development branch onto my feature branch
2. Resolve conflicts if any
3. Continue developing in your feature branch

**The problem**

The second step is the chicken's neck here. On rebasing it gives me conflicts for **every** commit of that branch. This is really iterative and redundant. Note, I can't always rebase the development branch immediately since my own work in my branch remains in progress.

**What I tried?**

1. To `squash` and reduce my commits as much as possible (but this helps least, as most of the times there is nothing to squash)
2. To `stash` my on going changes, and rebase development and then unstash my changes. (but here, I get conflicts as well)
3. Using `-preserve-merges` with rebase. (but everyone here shouts that using this is totally **discouraged**)

So, what is the optimal approach in dealing with rebasing development onto feature branch with least conflicts when the feature branch itself has numerous commits. I am a fresher, and so a reply with a helpful explanation (or link) will be of much help to proceed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The workflow is sound (rebase).
But the conflicts should not be resolved every time over and over again.

For that, you have [`git rerere`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere): activate it (`git config --global rerere.enabled true`), resolve the conflict one last time (or do a [manual re-training](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16541107/6309), or [use `contrib/rerere-train.sh`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45664714/6309)), and your next rebase will resuse those conflict resolution at your next rebase.

Comment: Wow never heard about rerere ..Will try this for sure...Thanks

Comment: @KaranDesai Again as I mentioned, you can retrain rerere in order to avoid having to resolve (again) your merge conflicts. Once the retraining is done, you can try again a rebase: there shouldn't be any more conflicts (on past commits)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to **keep your feature small** (one or two days), and your feature branch will be small as well. 
Another way would be to rebase not every time something got pushed to development branch but only sometimes, or just once before the merge. 
Again you need to keep the feature small or you will have too many conflics all at once.

About your question, you cannot minimize the number of conflics in a rebase. If there are conflics you cannot avoid them.

But there is one way git can help you: I suggest you to enable [rerere](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere) which stands for *reuse recorded resolution*. With this, git records how you resolve a conflict and the next time the conflict appears, the resolution is reapplied so that you find the conflict already resolved. This sould speed up your workflow.

You can enable rerere globally with

```
git config --global rerere.enabled true
```

Comment: Woah rerere is not rare, that means (only I didn't know it). Same suggestion was in previous answer as well. +1 for adding syntax to enable it globally..Will surely try

Answer (score 0):

Try to **git merge** from the development branch into the feature branch before you perform the **git rebase**. It will be more informative in the way.