# How to automate git pull origin without needing to comment?

Tags: git, automation, git-pull

I have a remote server on which I run a number of scripts.
I just run my scripts on that server, and do my editing and saving and pushing to bitbucket cloud as my origin repository from other locations.

How do I automate the "git pull origin" command for that windows server.
This isnt about running a command or script in the Task Scheduler, but more like I have to manually comment everytime when I do a "git pull origin".

I just wish to run "git pull origin" to make sure my scripts are up to date on the server in the morning before running.

But I am having trouble doing it without being forced to manually enter a message or other manual behavior.

Maybe do I have a setting wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by 'I have to manually comment everytime when I do a "git pull origin"'? It sounds like you might have local changes on your server and you're being asked to deal with a conflict.

Comment: Oh that makes sense, there might be a corruption, I think for this you use git pull origin --rebase right?

Comment: It depends entirely on (a) what you want to do and (b) what you have. You have't provided enough information to know the right answer. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think for this you use git pull origin --rebase right

No: weather you are doing a merge (pull) or a rebase (pull --rebase), any concurrent modification on the *same* set of files would potentially involve conflicts, to be resolved manually.

If you see the same conflict over and over again, do consider `git rerere`, that I [detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45831259/6309).

That, or maintain a separate clone of the repo, in which you make no modification, and can do a `git pull` without ever having to enter any comment.