# How to squash consecutive commit objects into one?

Tags: git, squash

My git object graph looks like below. I want to squash commits `2fb14b7`, `39224ad`, `fe9252d`, and `3e7a060` into one single commit.

```
* 650c464        (temp) adding hw2.txt
| * dd3674a      (master) added hw3
| | * 8dc0857    (FIX_REVIEW_COMMENTS) added hwa
| |/  
| * c39d943      hw2 added in master
| | *   e2a1c13  (HEAD, refs/stash, trying_to_squash) WIP on temp: 2fb14b7 hw7
| | |\  
| | | * 429b1de  index on temp: 2fb14b7 added hw7
| | |/  
| | * 2fb14b7    <-- added hw7
| | * 39224ad    <-- (another_branch) added hw3
| | * fe9252d    <-- hw2 added in master
| | * 3e7a060    <-- adding hw2.txt
| |/  
|/|   
* | ba55177      (old_fixes) added hw4
|/  
* a1ede1f        added another hello world to hw1
* 2ea750a        added hw1
```

Below is what I tried (and did not understand why it did not work).

> **Q1. Why does this not squash?**

```
$ git checkout 2fb14b7 -b try_to_commit
$ git merge --squash 3e7a060
 (nothing to squash)Already up-to-date.
$
```

> **Q2. What does this do to my repository?**

```
$ git rebase --interactive 3e7a060
$ # I choose pick for the first commit object, and squash for the rest
$ # but somehow this complicates my repository graph even more!
```

Comment: You mean '2fb14b7, 39224ad, fe9252d, and 3e7a060'?

Comment: @Moeb can you explain what you mean by interactive rebase "complicating your repository graph even more"?

Comment: @ColdHawaiian: it created new branches, instead of simplifying my repository.

Comment: the reason for that is that you have a some changes stashed on the old HEAD. pop the stash and your repo graph will look nice again.

Comment: @Moeb can you show what your commit graph looks like afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

Update from 2021 (8 years later): you would [not use `git checkout`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309) anymore, but [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch)

```
git switch -c try_to_commit 2fb14b7
```

> Why does this not squash?

Because you are merging a parent (past) commit (3e7a060) to a new one 2fb14b7

```
| | *   e2a1c13  (HEAD, refs/stash, trying_to_squash) WIP on temp: 2fb14b7 hw7
| | |\  
| | | * 429b1de  index on temp: 2fb14b7 added hw7
| | |/  
| | * 2fb14b7    <-- added hw7                   (more recent commit)
| | * 39224ad    <-- (another_branch) added hw3
| | * fe9252d    <-- hw2 added in master
| | * 3e7a060    <-- adding hw2.txt              (past old commit)
```

I would rather create the branch on the past commit, and squash-merge the more recent commit:

```
git switch -c try_to_commit 3e7a060
git merge --squash 2fb14b7
```

What does this do to my repository?

```
 git rebase --interactive 3e7a060
```

It attempts to replay the current branch `try_to_commit` on top of 3e7a060: that should allow to pick/squash commits, but don't forget to then replay e2a1c13 on top of the replayed branch.

I would rather rebase the all branch try_to_commit, made from e2a1c13 instead of 3e7a060, and using the [Git 2.18, Q2 2018, `--rebase-merges` option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50555740/6309):

```
git switch -c try_to_commit c39d943
git rebase --rebase-merges --interactive 3e7a060
```

---

Note that the message `(nothing to squash)Already up-to-date` will change with git 2.32 (Q2 2021): a few variants of the informational message "`Already up-to-date`" has been rephrased.

See [commit ad9322d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ad9322da033fac2678cab90988321549e0f1c86f) (02 May 2021) by [Josh Soref (`jsoref`)](https://github.com/jsoref).
See [commit 80cde95](https://github.com/git/git/commit/80cde95eecbc3e0812a92eaa7bcd534dd256ceab) (02 May 2021) by [Eric Sunshine (`sunshineco`)](https://github.com/sunshineco).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5feebdd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5feebddd8683f40bc53de0f6ea0883fc13042dc3), 11 May 2021)</sup>

> ### [`merge`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ad9322da033fac2678cab90988321549e0f1c86f): fix swapped "up to date" message components
>
> <sup>Co-authored-by: Eric Sunshine</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Josh Soref</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Eric Sunshine</sup>

> The rewrite of [`git-merge`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ad9322da033fac2678cab90988321549e0f1c86f/Documentation/git-merge.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge))</sup> from shell to C in [1c7b76b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1c7b76be7d620bbaf2e6b8417f04012326bbb9df) ("Build in merge", 2008-07-07, Git v1.6.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fcab40a389e99786a8276108cdbc1cda8caf502f)) accidentally transformed the message:
>
> ```
> Already up-to-date. (nothing to squash)
> ```
>
> to:
>
> ```
> (nothing to squash)Already up-to-date.
> ```
>
> due to reversed `printf()` arguments.
>
> This problem has gone unnoticed despite being touched over the years by:
>
> - [7f87aff](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7f87aff22c0232a5ce327ea3d2923776936c97f4) ("Teach/Fix pull/fetch -q/-v options", 2008-11-15, Git v1.6.1-rc1 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/98cdf78c5cf1356757ccc4d25c212ae1f38339e4))
> - [bacec47](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bacec4784598ca35b9be7635cbb630ef59367b6b) ("`i18n`: `git-merge` basic messages", 2011-02-22, Git v1.7.5-rc1 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6c80cd298a9f2f36ae4e741cf65d94b7c184fb82))
> - tangentially by [bef4830](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bef4830e88008adf488d190c742e243cacc46e16) ("`i18n`: merge: mark messages for translation", 2016-06-17, Git v2.10.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2703572b3a005848ed058d2775fb933a17ac3656) listed in [batch #5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/79ed43c28f626a4e805f350a77c54968b59be6e9))
> - [7560f54](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7560f547e614244fe1d4648598d4facf7ed33a56) (`treewide`: correct several , 2017-08-23, Git v2.15.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8e36002adda45a35c6fc4daf81913c3d2102cb59) listed in [batch #7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c739cd12a9aa471f4acb3639e0b73935b650be68)) (treewide: correct several "up-to-date" to "up to date", 2017-08-23).
>
> Fix it by restoring the message to its intended order.