# How can there be conflicts in a git interactive rebase when I haven't made any changes?

Tags: git

I wanted to reword a commit in git so I did a `git rebase -i 00112233` or something similar and I get merge conflicts without making any changes to the commits that will be applied. I enter the merge command, the editor pops up, I accept what's there and there's a merge conflict.

My understanding of `git rebase -i` is that `HEAD` is set to `00112233` and then the commits after `00112233`  (which are already consistent since they've been applied to get to the current state) are applied in the order specified in the editor (which I haven't changed in this case). I can't figure out how that process would lead to a merge conflict.

What are any ways such a situation can occur?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the history in question is not linear, you may have to reapply the conflict resolution you employed when you first merged.  To iilustrate, if history is:

```
C:\Temp\TestRepo>git log --graph  --oneline
*   3fc0537 Merge branch 'branch'
|\
| * 79e29f9 branch
* | 0de3658 master
|/
* edead94 Initial revision
```

And the merge commit `3fc0537` contained a conflict:

```
C:\Temp\TestRepo>git log -1
commit 3fc053701a53a30a01469f560ad5057eab74d126
Merge: 0de3658 79e29f9
Author: Edward Thomson <ethomson@edwardthomson.com>
Date:   Thu Feb 6 17:55:59 2014 -0800

    Merge branch 'branch'

    Conflicts:
        file.txt
```

Then rebasing off `edead94` will produce a merge conflict.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there is a way to say 'just resolve the conflicts the way that they were resolved before'?

Comment: It looks like `--preserve-merges` is relevant here. This question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915430/what-exactly-does-gits-rebase-preserve-merges-do-and-why has a pretty good answer.

Comment: @testuser Also, to re-resolve conflicts, you might checkout the `git rerere` tool: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rerere.html