# git copy a single commit by rebasing

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have two branches and one of them is always up to date with master by rebasing, but after a few changes I have some conflicts between two branches and rebasing got a bit painful. Now I wonder is there a way to get the latest commit from master, as I did a rebase?
**I have this:**

```
-- -- -- -- -- XX (Master)
             \
               -- -- -- -- -- (Branch 2)
```

**I want a PAINLESS WAY to get this:**

```
-- -- -- -- -- XX (Master)
                \
                  -- -- -- -- -- (Branch 2)
```

Rebasing asks to resolve set of conflicts while rewinding commits from `Branch 2`, though commit `XX` doesn't have any conflicts with commits on `Branch 2`. `cherry-pick`-ing creates new commit which I don't want to have, because it mixes up branches.

Comment: What you are asking to do is to _rewrite_ the history of Branch 2, by introducing one or more new commits from `Master`, and then replaying commits on your branch on top of this.  `git rebase` is probably the least painful way of doing this.  If, as you say, there isn't much friction caused by the new commits in `Master`, then the rebase should go smoothly.

Comment: Do you have something against simply merging master into branch2 instead of rebasing?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want to shift a single commit to history of `Branch 2` without again applying commits with conflicts by merging again

Comment: @zazu You _can't_ do this in Git, you would need to reapply all subsequent commits in `Branch 2`.

Comment: @JoePhillips it does not matter, I just dont want to merge conflicts

Comment: You're asking to rebase without conflicts, but the additional commit you want will cause conflicts.  How do you expect that it will automatically work itself out?  You can tell it to automatically resolve conflicts, but it wont necessarily be right.

Comment: @jbu no, I have conflict in a different file, which is not related to commit `XX`

Comment: oh interesting...have you tried --preserve-merges?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25670519/git-rebase-preserve-merges-fails - I've never personally used it, but it seems interesting

Comment: @jbu wow, that worked like a charm, thanks a lot! I think now I get what was the problem

Comment: This link explained things really well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915430/what-exactly-does-gits-rebase-preserve-merges-do-and-why  .  Since I've never used it, I would definitely read this carefully before using it.