# git rebase's --preserve-merges not strong enough

Tags: git, git-merge, rebase, git-rebase

I want to rebase, editing an older commit of mine, after which there have been merging involving conflicts. I know about `git rebase --preserve-merges`:

[How to rebase a merge but keep the merge commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33692857/how-to-rebase-a-merge-but-keep-the-merge-commit)

but - it doesn't do its job good enough. Instead of just resolving conflicts in favor of "ours", it balks at cases of both my branch and the merged branch having made changes which conflict with each other. I need the merge to be resolved exactly as it had originally been (assuming, of course, the relevant text/code has not been affected by my rebase). Is it possible to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-rebase%5D+merge

Comment: @phd what does that have to do with my question?

Comment: It answers that you should do `git rebase --rebase-merges`

Answer (score 1):

```
The --rebase-merges mode is similar in spirit to the deprecated --preserve-merges but works with interactive rebases, where
commits can be reordered, inserted and dropped at will.
```

according to the man page, you should be using --rebase-merges (unless you are on an older git version)

but when you try it you'll see that there is a whole language you have to learn with this one, so that might lead to more questions

I still use `--preserve-merges` for the simple stuff I do, but `--rebase-merges` might be the stronger solution you are looking for

Comment: Every time I try to use the "new and improved" --rebase-merges option, it ends up completely butchering my branch, so I have to undo everything. I came searching today for how to have the old --preserve-merges behavior, since now the docs don't even advertise it anymore, but I'm glad it still works (just tried it)!