# How to rebase(edit) to all sub branches

Tags: git

My current git tree is

```
A-B-C (branch 1)
    |
    E-F-G (branch 2)
        |
        H-I (branch 3)
```

I want to rebase (edit) in commit B of branch 1 and it should reflect/propagate that edit commit in all other sub branches of branch 1.
Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git: How to rebase many branches (with the same base commit) at once?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866218/git-how-to-rebase-many-branches-with-the-same-base-commit-at-once)

Comment: I have seen the above link... I guess it is rebasing onto?.... And its moving a commit ahead from upstream... What i need is to edit the previous commit in history from a base branch.. And revise all its instances.. Could you please tell me more about your approach?

Comment: If its simply few branches you can use cherry pick on each sub branch to take that particular commit.

Comment: Did that already :) but trying for a robust solution to handle it in big projects

Comment: `git rebase -i`

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43711961/rebase-a-branch-that-has-child-branches - but unfortunately that question doesn't have a succinct solution.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "big projects"? The number of files and such in those commits shouldn't make a big difference in the process but if you mean "projects where lots of people are involved" then I would recommend you stay away from rebasing in this case, unless all of those branches are "yours". Rewriting history when multiple people are working together is not a good workflow.

Comment: Yes... That is a good advice, thanx, but just to be having a utility that could work in worse case.. I am trying.. And by big projects i meam that if we are having a lot of branches in the same manner as above and a similar fix needs to be provided to all

Comment: If the fix simply needs to be provided to all the branches, make another branch out from B, commit your fix there, then merge that branch into all the branches you want the fix in. No need to rewrite history at all.

Comment: That is what i did, but just in case where history needs to be edited.. Just a case