# A faster way to `git rebase --preserve-merges`

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I use git by creating a series of feature branches, and merging them to master when they're done with `git merge --no-ff`. This creates empty merge commits useful to identify start and end points of previous feature branches.

In order to handle multiple concurrent branches, or even nested branches, I use rebase. I never merge back, I always rebase my branches upon the latest commits, test and finally merge with `--no-ff` once everything is done. With nested branches, I do the same: multiple branches are merged sequentially onto the main branch, which is itself merged to master in the end.

In order to keep information about merges with nested branches, I often use `git rebase --preserve-merges`. This does exactly what I want and I have no problems with my workflow.

My main problem with git is that `git rebase --preserve-merges` is very slow (sometimes taking about 2 seconds per commit). After reading [What exactly does git's "rebase --preserve-merges" do (and why?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915430/what-exactly-does-gits-rebase-preserve-merges-do-and-why) I realize that git must perform a lot of work to preserve the merges, since git has to work on arbitrary graphs.

What I was wondering is this: since my workflow pretty much results in a graph equivalent to a linear history, is there a way to perform a `git rebase --preserve-merge` equivalent in a faster way, given that I guarantee "linearity" of history with only empty merge commits? I don't mind using scripts or weird commands, as long as the final result is correct.

```
     A-B-C
    /     \   
(1)--------D-- master
    \
     \---F-----I-- feature
      \ / \   /
       E   G-H

     A-B-C   E   G-H
    /     \ / \ /   \
(2)--------D---F-----I-feature
         master
```

**tl; dr:** How to transform (1) into (2) knowing that the underlying history is linear so `git rebase --preserve-merges` doesn't have to do as much work and does it fast?

Answer (score 2):

You *might* be able to speed it all up a little bit by rewriting it from a bash script to something more clever (e.g., in Python, run `git rev-list --parents` with an appropriate set of revision delimiters, and collect up all the parent information before beginning the copy operations), but fundamentally it's just hard.  As the answer in that other link notes in passing, `git rebase -p` also doesn't exactly *preserve* merges so much as *re-create* them.  In the fully general case—which I know you're ignoring in favor of more limited special cases; I only mention this for completeness—`git rebase -p` fails completely on merges that have had special options or processing applied (`--no-commit` merges with manual modifications to produce an "evil merge", or merges run with `-X rename-threshold` or `-X ours` or similar), since the special-case information is, in effect, only stored in the resulting tree.  The rebase code does not even look for it (this would take much longer: it would have to reproduce the original merge first just to see if a no-option merge would have re-created the original result).

All that aside, the speed (or lack of speed) of these options depends on the size of your repository and its files, and whether you use Windows (extremely slow) or a Unixish system (much faster).  There is no reason I know of that Windows should be so terribly slow to run scripts, but clearly it is, because the Git folks keep rewriting things in C to make them perform acceptably on Windows because the scripts are so slow.

Hence, if you're doing this on Windows, one way to speed it up a lot is to stop using Windows. :-) (You could do this just for the duration of the rebase itself, using `git push` and `git fetch` to coordinate between Windows and Linux-or-whatever.)

Comment: Unfortunately I'm on Ubuntu, so I don't think it depends on that. The repo where I last had this problem was used by many people with a messy history, so that could have been a factor in the slowness of the command. However, I disagree that in my special case it's difficult: a simple `git rebase` does it correctly very fast; my only difference would be that instead of skipping the merge commits it should copy/recreate them. Shouldn't be that hard, right?

Comment: In a big repository, I have seen `git merge` itself take 30 minutes. Presumably yours is not *this* big, but repeating a merge could be the culprit. Since interactive rebase is (or was mostly, it's starting to change in Git) a shell script, you could find out by setting the `-x` flag and watching it operate, to see where the delays are.

Comment: `git rev-list --parents` does not work saying `usage: git rev-list [OPTION] <commit-id>... [ -- paths... ]`

Comment: @alper: `git rev-list --parents HEAD` works fine for me. Did you forget to give `git rev-list` a starting point commit? I forgot to mention that this is required. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Reminder (2021)

| IMPORTANT |
| --- |
| Starting Git 2.22, Q2 2019, the [old rebase script is no more](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4f3036cfa1ffe2470f1afafe541fea8d58d9282b) |

- Git 2.22 (Apr. 2019) has retired the old `git rebase` script.
  See [commit d03ebd4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d03ebd411c651641eab823f0807705f4af65c9b1) (18 Mar 2019) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
  <sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4f3036c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4f3036cfa1ffe2470f1afafe541fea8d58d9282b), 16 Apr 2019)</sup>
- Git 2.23 (Q3 2019) finalize the cleanup, and points out that the only remaining scripted part of `git rebase` is [the `--preserve-merges` backend](https://github.com/git/git/blob/082ef75b7bfc90ac236afbb857a9552a026832b8/git-rebase--preserve-merges.sh).
  See [commit 082ef75](https://github.com/git/git/commit/082ef75b7bfc90ac236afbb857a9552a026832b8), [commit c3c003e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c3c003e722317eacd2adf98d1758d7991cb9834f), [commit d4fe60e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d4fe60ed332a6031bd76db9c65c17ab3e0d7c0f5), [commit b2b9a23](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b2b9a23116ffaa4ccd4904b0cfffbb48bf6ec749), [commit 311c00a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/311c00aae87b0b91e65140dea3d2ef54119c294a) (14 May 2019) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
  <sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ed7f8ac](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ed7f8acbaa3d986a8b4e8d625b2f54355ce15ef0), 13 Jun 2019)</sup>
- With Git 2.34 (Q4 2021), the "`--preserve-merges`" option of "[`git rebase`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/223a1bfb5821387981c700654e4edd2443c5a7fc/Documentation/git-rebase.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase))</sup> **has been removed**.
  See [commit 17919c3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/17919c3585ba9df9c65ea4a5f7300543dfba5f9f), [commit 06aa5e4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/06aa5e4ea4f2c5bbf5ae80f31b0dbd5df267ba74), [commit 82db1f8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/82db1f8439bbde725a4dddb43f4e7c1cbe532a13), [commit ff8d6e5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ff8d6e5a665cf677a2bdec6f62b47b8987dae3c1), [commit 5b55b32](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5b55b32bd2c36fea43f516fa36f8276655954f40), [commit 0a159d6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0a159d65d6f30154a70ab83b52e9f772901862b1), [commit a74b350](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a74b35081c51adbde3ef01870ba03e859db33be6), [commit 52f1e82](https://github.com/git/git/commit/52f1e82178e75bdf876799770922bc34fdf6fae4), [commit aa4df10](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aa4df107e72a7a8bd2f149ecb58edfe9dde8576b), [commit ab7c7c2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ab7c7c219b487ad8cde94c8c1155977cb2efd52b), [commit 6df8755](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6df8755c7b953665bb1960e660fceb5acc2b2a23) (07 Sep 2021) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
  <sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 223a1bf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/223a1bfb5821387981c700654e4edd2443c5a7fc), 18 Oct 2021)</sup>

---

Original answer 2018:

> My main problem with git is that `git rebase --preserve-merges` is very slow

That might not be so slow with Git 2.20+ (Q4 2018), considering it includes a rewrite of the "rebase" machinery in C.
No more shell script.

| IMPORTANT |
| --- |
| Again, let's be clear: starting Git 2.22, Q2 2019, the [old rebase script is no more](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4f3036cfa1ffe2470f1afafe541fea8d58d9282b) |

See [commit ac7f467](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ac7f467fef8b836084afdce5eded047c79a6858d), [commit c7b64aa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c7b64aa0f3a83ed574d9d374bf2639c3c091120c), [commit 55071ea](https://github.com/git/git/commit/55071ea248ef8040e4b29575376273e4dd061683) (06 Aug 2018) by [Pratik Karki (`prertik`)](https://github.com/prertik).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5ae5084](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5ae50845d8a30d7db32e139ce04b712f9deb99cd), 02 Nov 2018)</sup>

> ### rebase: start implementing it as a builtin

> This commit imitates the strategy that was used to convert the `difftool` to a builtin.
> We start by renaming the shell script `git-rebase.sh` to `git-legacy-rebase.sh` and introduce a `builtin/rebase.c` that simply executes the shell script version,
> unless the config setting `rebase.useBuiltin` is set to `true`.
>
> The motivation behind this is to rewrite all the functionality of the
> shell script version in the aforementioned `rebase.c`, one by one and
> be able to conveniently test new features by configuring
> `rebase.useBuiltin`.
>
> In the original `difftool` conversion, if `sane_execvp()` that attempts to
> run the legacy scripted version returned with non-negative status, the
> command silently exited without doing anything with success, but
> `sane_execvp()` should not return with non-negative status in the first
> place, so we use `die()` to notice such an abnormal case.
>
> We intentionally avoid reading the config directly to avoid
> messing up the `GIT_*` environment variables when we need to fall back to
> exec()ing the shell script.

---

See [commit 62c2393](https://github.com/git/git/commit/62c23938fae5b7a374388c64fbdf8ee9ecb51b92), [commit d8d0a54](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d8d0a546f04be2990d50425fe152af915bc3b82f) (14 Nov 2018) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4520c23](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4520c233742cca267e1c0ba55f04f35ef7e9baf7), 18 Nov 2018)</sup>

[The documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4520c233742cca267e1c0ba55f04f35ef7e9baf7/Documentation/config/rebase.txt#L1-L13) now states:

> ```
> rebase.useBuiltin:
> ```

> Set to `false` to use the legacy shellscript implementation if `git rebase`.
> Is `true` by default, which means use the built-in rewrite of it in C.
>
> **The C rewrite is first included with Git version 2.20**.
> This option serves an an escape hatch to re-enable the legacy version in case any
> bugs are found in the rewrite.
> This option and the shellscript version `git-rebase` will be removed in some future release.
>
> If you find some reason to set this option to `false` other than one-off testing you should report the behavior difference as a bug in git.

---

With Git 2.21 (Feb. 2019), "`git rebase --merge`" as been reimplemented by reusing the internal machinery used for "`git rebase -i`".

See [commit 68aa495](https://github.com/git/git/commit/68aa495b590d417e88562ab1e5da7d84d0531f21), [commit c91c944](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c91c944a068e12eca5d4b6040ad05c7068437111), [commit 7b76ac6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7b76ac664cbe68c64bf79bd37e8b5d5fe690ba29), [commit 899b49c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/899b49c446fa645419676899c9409e2975a5dd26), [commit 45339f7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/45339f74ef87123ab79831310bf8047cebe5177b), [commit 5400677](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5400677903bdb852e0ca89e41e009afb8a1b6239), [commit 72ee673](https://github.com/git/git/commit/72ee67319f703201631b33697291720afd4e1d66), [commit c913c59](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c913c5964c3a7b5158a76c02721acbd0df6e2b40) (11 Dec 2018) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8fe9c3f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8fe9c3f21dff206acb464d86cbd3bf4dbbb94f38), 07 Feb 2019)</sup>

> ### `rebase`: implement `--merge` via the interactive machinery

> As part of an ongoing effort to make rebase have more uniform behavior, modify the merge backend to behave like the interactive one, by re-implementing it on top of the latter.
>
> Interactive rebases are implemented in terms of cherry-pick rather than the merge-recursive builtin, but cherry-pick also calls into the recursive merge machinery by default and can accept special merge strategies and/or special strategy options.
> As such, there really is not any need for having both `git-rebase--merge` and
> `git-rebase--interactive` anymore.
> Delete `git-rebase--merge.sh` and instead implement it in `builtin/rebase.c`.

> ### `rebase`: define linearization ordering and enforce it

See [commit c91c944](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c91c944a068e12eca5d4b6040ad05c7068437111) on performance.

Also, still Git 2.21 (Feb. 2019): "`git rebase --merge`" as been reimplemented by reusing the internal machinery used for "`git rebase -i`".

See [commit 29d03f8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/29d03f84a1bd0e27ab172bcd80382c5e2e8df1ec) (14 Feb 2019) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6f07c7b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6f07c7b91197aa06c5d8a05c67100c369012f933), 14 Feb 2019)</sup>

> ### rebase: implement --merge via the interactive machinery

> As part of an ongoing effort to make rebase have more uniform behavior, modify the merge backend to behave like the interactive one, by re-implementing it on top of the latter.
>
> Interactive rebases are implemented in terms of cherry-pick rather than the merge-recursive builtin, but cherry-pick also calls into the
> recursive merge machinery by default and can accept special merge strategies and/or special strategy options.
> As such, there really is not any need for having both `git-rebase--merge` and
> `git-rebase--interactive` anymore.
> Delete `git-rebase--merge.sh` and instead implement it in `builtin/rebase.c`.
>
> This results in a few deliberate but small user-visible changes:
>
> - The progress output is modified (see t3406 and t3420 for examples)
> - A few known test failures are now fixed (see t3421)
> - bash-prompt during a rebase --merge is now `REBASE-i` instead of `REBASE-m`.
>   Reason: The prompt is a reflection of the backend in use; this allows users to report an issue to the git mailing list with  the appropriate backend information, and allows advanced users to
>   know where to search for relevant control files.  (see t9903)

---

Since "`git rebase --preserve-merge`" as been reimplemented by reusing the internal machinery used for "`git rebase -i`", this Git 2.22 (Q2 2019) patch is of interest:

See [commit 460bc3c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/460bc3ce7386582b3259f8e3a2c1ace443ddb1ae), [commit 297b1e1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/297b1e177377444cba9a5364a4c6ce676ededb4d), [commit 0ea0847](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0ea0847ef0f6d548fe3a3c6720f99323408b2a50), [commit 73fdc53](https://github.com/git/git/commit/73fdc535d269ba1ac25cdb832d72d47abdede049), [commit 3389853](https://github.com/git/git/commit/338985317eb84007f0d08979e751cbf32a375a52), [commit 7d3488e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7d3488eb893ba53186770181171ee8ebc8100e18), [commit c44c246](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c44c24621da1cf45e2525b42d90982c78bffc207), [commit 0609b74](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0609b741a43dee2934ceb76850fea5963ab0c8f6), [commit 6023c92](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6023c928aa07128b4270446e7735beb20b2c8096), [commit 28dc09d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/28dc09de6d9dbe8270c60177948e50a13c9933ab), [commit 146839c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/146839c4b69ec47a356eb1156f2093ac5cc2cb60) (17 Apr 2019), and [commit fc4a673](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fc4a6735ee10b7699c22dfb58a9dd40f225e51bd) (19 Mar 2019) by [Phillip Wood (`phillipwood`)](https://github.com/phillipwood).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7ba06bc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7ba06bc3d026cee54437db5cfddfffe7b4d7a187), 13 May 2019)</sup>

> ### `rebase -i`: run without forking `rebase  --interactive`

> When the builtin rebase starts an interactive rebase it parses the options and then repackages them and forks `rebase--interactive`.
> Separate the option parsing in `cmd_rebase__interactive()` from the business logic to allow interactive rebases can be run without forking `rebase__interactive` by calling `run_rebase_interactive()` directly.
>
> Starting interactive rebases without forking makes it easy to debug
> the sequencer without worrying about attaching to child
> processes.
> Ævar has also reported that some of the [rebase perf tests are 30% faster](https://public-inbox.org/git/87y359cfjj.fsf@evledraar.gmail.com/).
>
> This patch also makes it easy to remove `cmd_rebase__interactive()` in
> the future when `git-legacy-rebase.sh` and `git-rebase--preserve-merges.sh` are retired.

---

---

"`git rebase -i`" (and friends) used to unnecessarily check out the tip of the branch to be rebased, which has been corrected with Git 2.26 (Q1 2020),

See [commit 767a9c4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/767a9c417eb2109dda71995c8fb8a884d3a35e6f) (24 Jan 2020) by [Alban Gruin (``)](https://github.com/).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d8b8d59](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d8b8d59054ed5ba2f79d3cb2fad0b5f0bfeb3ac1), 14 Feb 2020)</sup>

> ### [`rebase -i`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/767a9c417eb2109dda71995c8fb8a884d3a35e6f): stop checking out the tip of the branch to rebase
>
> <sup>Reported-by: SZEDER Gábor</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Alban Gruin</sup>

> One of the first things done when using a sequencer-based rebase (ie. `rebase -i`, `rebase -r`, or `rebase -m`) is to make a todo list.
>
> This requires knowledge of the commit range to rebase.
>
> To get the oid of the last commit of the range, the tip of the branch to rebase is checked out with `prepare_branch_to_be_rebased()`, then the oid of the head is read.
>
> After this, the tip of the branch is not even modified. The `am' backend, on the other hand, does not check out the branch.
>
> On big repositories, it's a performance penalty: with `rebase -i', the user may have to wait before editing the todo list while git is extracting the branch silently, and "quiet" rebases will be slower than` am'.
>
> Since we already have the oid of the tip of the branch in `opts->orig_head`, it's useless to switch to this commit.
>
> This removes the call to `prepare_branch_to_be_rebased()` in `do_interactive_rebase()`, and adds a `orig_head' parameter to` get_revision_ranges()`.
>
> `prepare_branch_to_be_rebased()` is removed as it is no longer used.
>
> This introduces a visible change: as we do not switch on the tip of the branch to rebase, no reflog entry is created at the beginning of the rebase for it.
>
> Unscientific performance measurements, performed on `linux.git`, are as follow:
>
> Before this patch:
>
> ```
> $ time git rebase -m --onto v4.18 463fa44eec2fef50~ 463fa44eec2fef50
>
> real    0m8,940s
> user    0m6,830s
> sys     0m2,121s
> ```
>
> After this patch:
>
> ```
> $ time git rebase -m --onto v4.18 463fa44eec2fef50~ 463fa44eec2fef50
>
> real    0m1,834s
> user    0m0,916s
> sys     0m0,206s
> ```

---

As notes with Git 2.26 (Q1 2020), "`git rebase`" has learned to use the merge backend (i.e. the machinery that drives "`rebase -i`") by default, while allowing "`--apply`" option to use the "`apply`" backend (e.g. the moral equivalent of "`format-patch piped to am`").

> The `rebase.backend` configuration variable can be set to customize.

See [commit 10cdb9f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/10cdb9f38adaa16aad64403bc931405564523985), [commit 2ac0d62](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2ac0d6273fa6618e1a8783e07e2363b3abba1f2a), [commit 8295ed6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8295ed690bf1d458f80cffdc17d663eb3ba5162a), [commit 76340c8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/76340c8107ba8e658f9cc76d1d220bac2944d1f1), [commit 980b482](https://github.com/git/git/commit/980b482d28482c307648c3abbcb16ae60843c7ae), [commit c2417d3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c2417d3af7574adc1fb14f7df31b862aa9551e2e), [commit 6d04ce7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6d04ce75c4dd4bf0aeda7383c4d791daa049c98a), [commit 52eb738](https://github.com/git/git/commit/52eb738d6b40bf8816727fcf7f39febc761ef0db), [commit 8af14f0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8af14f08596197d53c40b71ed014b030956a12be), [commit be50c93](https://github.com/git/git/commit/be50c938dfc1555ea62df455a41138e41503b952), [commit befb89c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/befb89ce7c43a0bd0de11909951dd3015874e9db), [commit 9a70f3d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9a70f3d4ae673e02e78b1061fcc8fc01bc8d9276), [commit 93122c9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/93122c985a3671bd4e15b3dbc6b457c981eb8c23), [commit 55d2b6d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/55d2b6d785da8c49d693d989c22f47622783903a), [commit 8a997ed](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8a997ed132f7b8709d1752b64779566600345375), [commit 7db00f0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7db00f0b3bc2c0bde616d45cf6e3a130e74e3024), [commit e98c426](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e98c4269c86019bfe057a91b4305f784365b6f0b), [commit d48e5e2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d48e5e21da980c6d439655a1292d0332b341c7d1) (15 Feb 2020), and [commit a9ae8fd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a9ae8fde2eb0c00723d850ba23ea8401864fab83), [commit 22a69fd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/22a69fda197f78410190469bf0fcb51f6f69730f) (16 Jan 2020) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 8c22bd9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8c22bd9ff9d4a355d3546181698307a797fd2bd2), 02 Mar 2020)</sup>

> ### [`rebase`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/10cdb9f38adaa16aad64403bc931405564523985): rename the two primary rebase backends
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>

> **Rename the 'interactive' backend to 'merge'** because:
>
> - 'interactive' as a name caused confusion; this backend has been used for many kinds of non-interactive rebases, and will probably be used in the future for more non-interactive rebases than interactive ones given that we are making it the default.
> - 'interactive' is not the underlying strategy; merging is.
> - the directory where state is stored is not called `.git/rebase-interactive` but `.git/rebase-merge`.

---

With Git 2.27 (Q2 2020), you can also allow "`git rebase`" to reapply all local commits, even if the may be already in the upstream, without checking first.

```
git rebase --reapply-cherry-picks
```

That would accelerate the rebase process.

See [commit 0fcb4f6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0fcb4f6b62c87a73971890070dea847b56176338) (11 Apr 2020) by [Jonathan Tan (`jhowtan`)](https://github.com/jhowtan).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d6d561d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d6d561db1c0a14e8b89149694c0c662096c5fc9d), 22 Apr 2020)</sup>

> ### [`rebase --merge`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0fcb4f6b62c87a73971890070dea847b56176338): optionally skip upstreamed commits
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jonathan Tan</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Elijah Newren</sup>

> When rebasing against an upstream that has had many commits since the original branch was created:
>
> ```
> O -- O -- ... -- O -- O (upstream)
>  \
>   -- O (my-dev-branch)
> ```
>
> it must read the contents of every novel upstream commit, in addition to the tip of the upstream and the merge base, because "`git rebase`" attempts to exclude commits that are duplicates of upstream ones.
>
> This can be a significant performance hit, especially in a partial clone, wherein a read of an object may end up being a fetch.
>
> Add a flag `--reapply-cherry-picks` to "`git rebase`" to allow suppression of this feature.
> This flag only works when using the "`merge`" backend.
>
> This flag changes the behavior of `sequencer_make_script()`, called from `do_interactive_rebase()` <- `run_rebase_interactive()` <- `run_specific_rebase()` <- `cmd_rebase()`. With this flag, `limit_list()` (indirectly called from `sequencer_make_script()` through `prepare_revision_walk()`) will no longer call `cherry_pick_list()`, and thus `PATCHSAME` is no longer set.
> Refraining from setting `PATCHSAME` both means that the intermediate commits in upstream are no longer read (as shown by the test) and means that no `PATCHSAME`-caused skipping of commits is done by `sequencer_make_script()`, either directly or through `make_script_with_merges()`.

---

With Git 2.30 (Q1 2021), "`git-parse-remote`" shell script library outlived its usefulness.

See [commit 66d36b9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/66d36b94af6351d1e9b68a871d5faeb8a27d8a33) (24 Nov 2020) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
See [commit a89a2fb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a89a2fbfccd88bc8a3c8cce8d7bc03de3830ea25), [commit e63f7b0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e63f7b0acba326a47282036afffb83e2b3eb023d), [commit 1c15180](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1c1518071c7fa79de13b8c599d8dbb371950b033) (14 Nov 2020) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e89ecfb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e89ecfbb13f600e7fc0272c29de432e424a97aaa), 03 Dec 2020)</sup>

> ### [`parse-remote`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a89a2fbfccd88bc8a3c8cce8d7bc03de3830ea25): remove this now-unused library
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> The previous two commits removed the last use of a function in this library, but most of it had been dead code for a while.
> Only the `"get_default_remote"` function was still being used.
>
> Even though we had a manual page for this library it was never intended (or I expect, actually) used outside of [git.git](https://github.com/git/git). Let's just remove it, if anyone still cares about a function here they can pull them into their own project.
>
> 1. Last use of `error_on_missing_default_upstream()`:
>    [d03ebd411c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d03ebd411c651641eab823f0807705f4af65c9b1) ("rebase: remove the rebase.useBuiltin setting",
>    2019-03-18)
> 2. Last use of `get_remote_merge_branch()`: [49eb8d39c7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/49eb8d39c78f161231e63293df60f343d208f409) ("Remove>     contrib/examples/*", 2018-03-25)
> 3. https://lore.kernel.org/git/87a6vmhdka.fsf@evledraar.gmail.com/

---

With Git 2.32 (Q2 2021), the final hint that used to have a scripted git rebase is removed.

See [commit 9bcde4d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9bcde4d53143f0b74604fa012c703f3794f94f80) (23 Mar 2021) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit dc2a073](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dc2a073036ccbd3d8aa707b98e996b6fb9bcd751), 30 Mar 2021)</sup>

> ### [`rebase`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9bcde4d53143f0b74604fa012c703f3794f94f80): remove transitory rebase.useBuiltin setting & env
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>
> <sup>Acked-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> Remove the rebase.useBuiltin setting and the now-obsolete `GIT_TEST_REBASE_USE_BUILTIN` test flag.
>
> This was left in place after my [d03ebd4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d03ebd411c651641eab823f0807705f4af65c9b1) ("`rebase`: remove the rebase.useBuiltin setting", 2019-03-18, Git v2.22.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4f3036cfa1ffe2470f1afafe541fea8d58d9282b) listed in [batch #5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ffac537e6cbbf934b08745a378932722df287a53)) to help anyone who'd used the experimental flag and wanted to know that it was the default, or that they should transition their test environment to use the builtin rebase unconditionally.
>
> It's been more than long enough for those users to get a headsup about this.
> So remove all the scaffolding that was left in-place after [d03ebd4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d03ebd411c651641eab823f0807705f4af65c9b1).
> I'm also removing the documentation entry, if anyone still has this left in their configuration they can do some source archaeology to figure out what it used to do, which makes more sense than exposing every Git user reading the documentation to this legacy configuration switch.

---

With Git 2.36 (Q2 2022), `git rebase -m` is safer:

See [commit 38c541c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/38c541ce94048cf72aa4f465be9314423a57f445), [commit cd1528e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cd1528ef8ef9847fc27cff4016bf073f04729504), [commit 7700ab0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7700ab087b82f71d19134141045b95063e407344), [commit 6ae8086](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6ae8086161d81a707ff36dfdc07f57e4f473e0fd), [commit ee464c4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ee464c4e37c7f34c4e5ba2fce35df4149083e5ea), [commit b7de153](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b7de153bd9332a992baa6f937372f0b1833f61e5), [commit 1526d0f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1526d0fcfd20efca24bc96a4bc14c8d5459ec470), [commit d6a9f5e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d6a9f5ea8e97dd9435e5fa02cc129c1b241934f2), [commit 1946d45](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1946d45844c65ede4e3a514a5decf16612ad79f0), [commit 4840002](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4840002a5f44a4c256c55f70c59d3b0506d14e21), [commit ab2fba0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ab2fba0868860e610619f885031217d9cc63097a), [commit 69f4c23](https://github.com/git/git/commit/69f4c23009ee30faeb61a831f4265791c945783e), [commit bd55eee](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bd55eee04b698af6c10c77b24f88601814771ac8), [commit ae42fa4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ae42fa4c03ef0ffe36468f8918b3d404a277da50) (26 Jan 2022) by [Phillip Wood (`phillipwood`)](https://github.com/phillipwood).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit bcd020f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bcd020f88e1e22f38422ac3f73ab06b34ec4bef1), 18 Feb 2022)</sup>

> ### [`rebase -m`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/38c541ce94048cf72aa4f465be9314423a57f445): don't fork `git checkout`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Phillip Wood</sup>

> Now that `reset_head()` can handle the initial checkout of onto correctly use it in the "merge" backend instead of forking git checkout".
> This opens the way for us to stop calling the post-checkout hook in the future.
> Not running "[`git checkout`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/38c541ce94048cf72aa4f465be9314423a57f445/Documentation/git-checkout.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout))</sup> means that `rebase -i/m` no longer recurse submodules when checking out onto (thanks to Philippe Blain for pointing this out).
> As the rest of rebase does not know what to do with submodules this is probably a good thing.
> When using merge-ort rebase ought be able to handle submodules correctly if it parsed the submodule config, such a change is left for a future patch series.
>
> The "`apply`" based rebase has avoided forking `git checkout` since [ac7f467](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ac7f467fef8b836084afdce5eded047c79a6858d) (`builtin/rebase`: support running , 2018-08-07, Git v2.20.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5ae50845d8a30d7db32e139ce04b712f9deb99cd) listed in [batch #8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d582ea202b626dcc6c3b01e1e11a296d9badd730)) ("builtin/rebase: support running "[`git rebase`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/38c541ce94048cf72aa4f465be9314423a57f445/Documentation/git-rebase.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase))</sup> `<upstream>`, 2018-08-07).
> The code that handles the checkout was moved into `libgit` by [b309a97](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b309a9710899dab2f76455526f573a90fad5d13c) ("`reset`: extract `reset_head()` from rebase", 2020-04-07, Git v2.27.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bf10200871d9e7e1fc9f54aca9b2fe40bc4e4ac7) listed in [batch #5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d61d20c9b413225793f8a0b491bbbec61c184e26)).