# Git can't execute editor for interactive rebase even though it works for merges

Tags: git

Pretty much what the title says. I get the following error:

```
/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-legacy-rebase--interactive: line 94: rebase-editor: command not found
Could not execute editor
```

I know there are similar questions out there but all I found on those was "editor is not set correctly, do xy". Which I did. My config lists:

```
core.editor='G:/Anwendungen/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin
```

I still get the error though. Weirdly when I do *--no-ff* merges, notepad++ opens just fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: The text `line 94: rebase-editor: command not found` indicates that the rebase command thinks your chosen editor is `rebase-editor`, not `G:/Anwen...[snipped]`. Why *that* is the case, I don't know, but `/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-legacy-rebase--interactive` is a shell script that implements the older interactive rebase. Being a shell script, you can just read it and figure out why it thinks that.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I looked and that's the line ```eval "$GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR" '"$@"'```. Doesn't look too fishy from my noob-perspective. I wonder why git would use the legacy-rebase command in the first place as a non-legacy one exists.

Comment: As you found with VonC, this was due to setting the sequence editor. The `$GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR` selection is used to edit the *instruction sheet*. The `$GIT_EDITOR` selection is used to edit later *commit messages*. Normally both are the same editor, but you can set one or both differently for special purposes. It's a bad idea to *configure* them differently, as you've just seen, as this bites you later...

Comment: True true! Thanks for the additional info on the internal ongoings! I appreciate the opportunity to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and upgrade Git to [the latest 2.30.1](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases): my Git For Windows does not include any `git-legacy...` script.

As documented in "[A faster way to `git rebase --preserve-merges`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53145636/6309)", `git rebase` is now almost fully implemented in C, and should use your `git config core.editor` setting.

The OP confirms:

- the issue persists even with 2.30.1
- the problem was with the [setting `sequence.editor`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-sequenceeditor): removing it means When using the default commit message editor instead.

Comment: Funny :D I just did that and wanted to come back to comment on the result, which is: it's still not working but with an updated error message.```hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... error: cannot spawn rebase-editor: No such file or directory
error: unable to start editor 'rebase-editor'``` (I made sure that ```core.editor``` is still set after the update.)

Comment: @Wolfone `'rebase-editor'` is not something that exists in Git. Can you see "rebase-editor" in the output of a `git config -l`?

Comment: Ha! Good hint! ```core.editor``` was not the culprit but ```sequence.editor```! I assume that this was still set by a cli-rebase-editor that I had installed some time ago. If you update your answer accordingly I will gladly accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @Wolfone Good catch. I have edited the answer accordingly.