# change committer name of commit having two parent after push

Tags: git, github

I am trying to change committer name using:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3042512/6097074.

I have commit to branch `A` taking pull from 'B' and after pull I got conflict to resolve but I wrongly commit from the other user.

Now I am trying to `rebase` it, but it is not showing that commit(merge commit after conflict resolve) in editor to change `PICK` to `EDIT`.

Below is my `gitk` image I want to change commit in Yellow highlight.

[image: conflict]

Answer (score 1):

(Note: if you have access to Git 2.18, you can try the fancy new rebase.  See [VonC's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50555740/1256452).  I do not know if it will work for this particular case.)

Rebasing *removes* merges, as the usual point of rebasing is to eliminate the need *for* merges.

There is a form of `git rebase` that *re-creates* merges (it just runs `git merge` again), but it's not the right way to do this for your case.  For your case, the right way to do this is for *you* to run `git merge` again—or perhaps for you not to do it at all.

Remember, `git pull` just means *run `git fetch`, then run `git merge`*.  (Or, if you tell it to run `git rebase` as its second Git command, *run `git fetch`, then run `git rebase`*.)  If you are a beginner to Git, I personally recommend *avoiding* `git pull`.  Run the two separate commands instead.  The results will make more sense.

You can use `git reset` to move your current branch name back to the point where the `git merge` has not yet occurred.  This will have the rather unfortunate, but crucial, side effect of tossing out all the *subsequent* commits as well, and of wiping out uncommitted work if you use `git reset --hard`.  That's a sign to help you realize that what you are doing is quite drastic.  Before you start, you will want to set up a name—a branch or tag name—to remember all the original commits, so that after `git reset --hard`, which drops all those commits from the current branch, you can still get to the original commits (which are now only on the new branch or tag name you just set up).

Having removed the merge, you can now run `git merge` again to *re-perform* the merge.  This time you can use a different committer name, if you wish.  Note that you get a *different commit*, with a different hash ID.

Having re-performed the merge, correctly this time, you can now copy all the subsequent commits.  You can do this one commit at a time, using `git cherry-pick` and their commit hash IDs.  Each copied commit gets a new committer name and time-stamp.  (Note that `git cherry-pick` re-uses the original *author* and *author time-stamp* by default, but you become the new committer.)  These new commits get new, different hash IDs from the originals.  This is necessary!  They sit atop the new and different merge commit, and hence they are different commits and need different IDs.

To copy all those commits faster, you can use `git rebase`!  This is in fact what `git rebase` does: it copies commits, so that the new ones come after wherever you are standing when you start the rebase.  (This is *why* it eliminates the need for merges.)  But for educational purposes, it makes more sense for you to use `git cherry-pick`.  That makes it clear *how* `git rebase` achieves its result.

Now that you have copied all the original commits to new, improved commits with different hash IDs, you can `git push` the new commits elsewhere.  However, anyone who already has the *original* commits is now forced to *switch* from the old (wrong) commits to the new (corrected) commits.  This is precisely why—and when—this kind of "rewriting history" is bad: when it makes more work for other people, who are now all annoyed with you for making them do all this work.  If you have never pushed those commits, no one else has them, so no one else gets annoyed; or, if you have made arrangements with everyone else in advance, no one else is *allowed* to get annoyed.

So in these two situations—originals never handed out, or you do a "history-rewrite" using `git push --force` but all parties have already agreed to deal with such pushes—this kind of rewrite is OK.  In other situations, you *can* still do this, but you may have to hope for forgiveness.

Comment: Would `git rebase --rebase-merges` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50555740/6309) help here?

Comment: @VonC: yes, though it might decide that there is nothing to do, and one might need to add `--force` (I have not tried it).

Comment: @torek could you Please steps of command to change merge commit author?
As per VonC answer I am not able to understand.

I used `git rebase --rebase-merges` and in return i am getting Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/. What this means?

Comment: Again, you're not going to *change* any commits. What you will do, regardless of how you do it, is to make *new* commits. Any commit you make uses your configured `user.name` and `user.email` as the committer name, which means you can change it temporarily. Alternatively, you can use the environment variables described in [the top level `git` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git.html) to temporarily override `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME`, `GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL`, `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME`, and `GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL` for the duration of creating the one merge commit.