# Rebasing on a shared branch when everyone rebases

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

I read up online that rebase command shouldn't be run on a public branch. I have the following scenario:

`master` having commits A1 <- A2 <- A3
`stable` branched from `master` at A1, having commit B1
`dev1` branched from `stable` at B1 and having commits C1 <- C2 <- C3
`dev2` branched from `dev1` at C2 and having commits D1 <- D2

Now if I want to update `stable` with `master`'s updates, I run `git rebase master` and do a force push. Now, `dev1` does a rebase on top of `stable` to get the `master`'s updates and `dev2` needing both `master` and `dev1` does a rebase on top of `dev1`.

In this scenario is it ok to run the rebase command on `stable`, `dev1` and `dev2` branches as long as I am following the order? If this isn't ok then what's the alternative to merge latest `master` to `stable` and latest `master`, `dev1` updates to `dev2`? The only thing I can think of is to create a pull request, `merge` the code and then re-branch. Is that the better alternative or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[With Git 2.18+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50555740/6309), you should not need to do all those rebases: only one:

```
git checkout stable
git rebase --rebase-merges master
```

`dev1` and `dev2` should be rebased as well: you will need to reset your local branches to those new rebased branches HEAD.

In your case, if you have set local branches for `master`, `stable`, `dev1` and `dev2`, that means only one rebase (of `stable`) will rebase all related branches (`dev1` and `dev2`)

```
--x--x--x--x (master)
      \
       s--s--s (stable)
              \
               d--d (dev1)
                   \
                    d--d (dev2)
```

A `git checkout stable; git rebase --rebase-merges master` will do:

```
--x--x--x--x (master)
            \
             s'--s'--s' (stable)
                      \
                       d'--d' (dev1)
                            \
                             d'--d' (dev2)
```

No need to rebase `stable`, then `dev1`, then `dev2`!

Comment: @torek Yes, I was a bit in a hurry when I wrote this. I have edited the answer.

Comment: I'll be honest, I'm having a hard time understanding what `--rebase-merges` does. Does this mean I don't need to force push after `rebase`? What sort of local branch resetting is required? I mean the `rebase` command would make the local branch sit on top of `master` or `stable` or `dev1` so where does the new rebased branch come into picture?

Comment: @linuxNoob I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: so if I force push the changes to remote `stable` after `--rebase-merges` and `dev1` and `dev2` pull it down then what do they need to do to sync their local `dev1` and `dev2` with the remote? More importantly, what if `dev2` doesn't exist in the remote yet? Is this what you're talking about with local branch being reset to rebased branches HEAD?

Comment: @linuxNoob you can push (for new branches) or force push. Anyone working on a forced pushed branch will need to: 1/ `git fetch` 2/ `git reset --hard origin/dev1` (for instance, to reset `dev1` working tree and history to `origin/dev1` you just fetched). Make sure to stash any work in progress first.

Comment: If `dev2` doesn't exist in remote yet then I'm assuming `git fetch` and `git reset --hard origin/dev1` will take care of rebasing `dev2` on top of  the rebased `dev1`?

Comment: @linuxNoob the idea behind git reset --hard is that you already force pushed *all* branches, so dev2 does exists in the remote. Another collaborator will fetch everything (including origin/dev2) and can then reset any local branch he/she wants.

Comment: if `dev2` exists only on local then they would have to manually `rebase` on top of `dev1`? It sounds like, this option requires all branches to be present in local before doing it. So if I am running `git rebase --rebase-merges stable` in my local then I must have `dev1` and `dev2` on my local?

Comment: @linuxNoob No, as illustrated, `dev2` would be rebased during the `git rebase --rebase-merges master`, alongside `stable` and `dev1`. Remember you rebase on top of `master`. You don't type `git rebase --rebase-merges stable`: that would rebase on top of `stable`.

Comment: > No, as illustrated, dev2 would be rebased during the git rebase --rebase-merges master, alongside stable and dev1.      How will this happen if I don't have `dev2` on remote or local?

Comment: @linuxNoob if dev2 does not exist at all anywhere, then it won't happen indeed: just create dev2 once the rebase is done, on top of dev1.