# Git branching strategy: During git rebase: couple file keeps conflicting

Tags: git, git-branch, git-rebase, git-branch-sculpting

Branching main Branch called MASTER
Created a Feature branch called FEATURE_BRANCH from MASTER
Created a sub feature branch called SUB_FEATURE_1

FEATURE_BRANCH the parent from which main sun features are created. This branch has to be rebased from MASTER and some features are done.

```
$ git checkout  FEATURE_BRANCH
$ git rebase master
$ git push origin FEATURE_BRANCH
$ git checkout SUB_FEATURE_1
$ git push origin FEATURE_BRANCH
$ git checkout  FEATURE_BRANCH
$ git commit --amend
$ git push origin FEATURE_BRANCH
$ git checkout SUB_FEATURE_1
$ git rebase FEATURE_BRANCH
```

On rebasing the sub feature branch there were merge conflicts for file `x.txt`. So corrected the file `git add` it and `git rebase --continue` .

But immediatly, the same file had merge conflicts. I fixed the file again and this time correct it all over again

The same file has the exact same merge conflicts. How is this happening?

IS the branching stategy right ? Why is the file having conflicts again ?

Comment: probably because this file was changed in several commits

Comment: This behavior is not abnormal. It's not very common either though. If you have a repeatable example setup, it would be good to post it.

Comment: You might want to consider using `git rerere`

Answer (score 1):

First, activate [`git rerere`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere) (as [explained here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rerere)) in order to not have to repeat the conflict resolution you are doing.

But second, and more importantly, do use [`git rebase --rebase-merges`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50555740/6309) (Git 2.18+)

That way, you won't have to rebase `sub_feature_1` branch: only one rebase (of `feature_1`) will be enough.

```
git checkout  FEATURE_BRANCH
git rebase --rebase-merges master
```