# git pull --rebase: passing --rebase-merges

Tags: git, rebase, git-pull

This is what I normally do when rebasing my current branch whilst keeping my local branching from getting flattened:

```
git fetch origin
git rebase -r origin/develop
```

`-r` is `--rebase-merges`, which I prefer over `--preserve-merges`

My question is: is there a way to pass this when doing `git pull --rebase` ?

Eg - I'd like to run the equivalent of the command above like so:

`git pull --rebase=rebasemerges origin develop`

instead of:

`git pull --rebase=preserve origin develop`

**edit: OK - looks like in 2.22, `--preserve-merges` is getting deprecated in favour of `--rebase-merges`. This is for `git rebase` though - fingers crossed the changes gets carried over to `git pull --rebase`

Comment: Here's a link to the background of my edit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50555740/857428

Answer (score 7, accepted):

git 2.22 has been released.

To answer my own question - this is the equivalent command:

`git pull --rebase=merges origin develop`

Taken from [the manual page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull):

> -r
>   --rebase[=false|true|merges|preserve|interactive] When true, rebase the current branch on top of the upstream branch after fetching. If
>   there is a remote-tracking branch corresponding to the upstream branch
>   and the upstream branch was rebased since last fetched, the rebase
>   uses that information to avoid rebasing non-local changes.
>
> When set to merges, rebase using git rebase --rebase-merges so that
>   the local merge commits are included in the rebase (see git-rebase[1](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)
>   for details).

To make this a default pull behaviour:

`git config --global pull.rebase merges`

Comment: Good update. Don't forget to pair that config with `rebase.autostash` set to true: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as I explained in "[What exactly does git's “`rebase --preserve-merges`” do (and why?)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50555740/6309)", the old `--preserve-merges` option will disappear.

And yes, the [`git pull -r` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull#Documentation/git-pull.txt--r) will be updated accordingly, but that is not yet implemented.
See the [patch in preparation here](https://public-inbox.org/git/pull.158.git.gitgitgadget@gmail.com/T/).