# Make git pull always use rebase=merges?

Tags: git

I have set `git config --global pull.rebase merges` like this question in SO: [git pull --rebase: passing --rebase-merges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56159981/git-pull-rebase-passing-rebase-merges)

but It doesn't work when I do `git pull`

The version I use is git version 2.38.1.windows.1

`git pull --rebase` seems like works

Update:
I have also set `pull.ff=only`.
`git pull` does not work, complains `git pull not possible to fast-forward aborting`

Comment: How does git behave _now_? As if the option were selected in the old days?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? The source code suggests that it should in fact work. (@AndreasLouv: did you mean `--preserve-merges` here? This was removed in Git 2.34.)

Comment: @eftshift0 It complains "git pull not possible to fast-forward aborting"

Comment: The question is for @AndreasLouv (and now also torek could also explain).

Comment: Just checked and `--rebase-merges` is still fine and well, at least in terms of rebase options: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/rebase.c#L1148

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean `git config --global pull.rebase true`?