# When will git-rebase fail with feature of feature branches?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

I have this git branch structure:

```
a-b-c             <---master
   \
    \d-e-f        <--feature1
        \
         \g-h-i   <--feature1_1
```

I need the possibility to rebase `feature1` on `master` to get bugfixes and other features and on `feature1_1` I need the possibility to get bugfixes and features from `master` and to get `bugfixes` from `feature1_1` too.

It should possible to merge `feature1` into `master` before `feature1_1` is ready.

Can there be any problems with the rebase (strange merge conflicts etc.) and if so what should I pay attention to?

Comment: Yes there can, and you should pay attention to them.

Answer (score 1):

If you do rebase feature1, do take advantage of the [recent (Git 2.18, Q2 2018) `git rebase --preserve-merges`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50555740/6309)

That will rebase everything (instead of just feature1, which would leave `feature1_1` still attached to a "phantom" old pre-rebase `feature1`):

Good:

```
a-b-c             <---master
     \
      \d'-e'-f'        <--feature1 rebased
           \
            \g'-h'-i'   <--feature1_1, also rebased!
```

But do pay attention to potential conflicts.

Bad (using `rebase` without `--preserve-merges`)

```
      /d'-e'-f'   <-- feature1 rebased (alone)
     /
a-b-c             <---master
   \
    \d-e          <-- partial old feature1 commits
        \
         \g-h-i   <--feature1_1, not rebased
```