# How can I move a commit back to a location in history before a branch was merged while leaving the branch intact?

Tags: git, merge, branch, rebase, cherry-pick

After merging a branch into master,
I realized that I ideally should have made a minor commit
before the branch was merged,
because it is directly related to the commit before the merge.
I have tried to clarify what the desired outcome looks like
in the simplified example below,
where

- B is the merge commit of X and Y into master,
- C is a commit that relates to the merged content,
- D does not touch any of the newly merged content and is directly related to A.

Current branch structure:

```
A----B-C-D
    /
 X-Y
```

The desired outcome is to move D right after A,
while leaving the rest as is:

```
A-D----B-C
      /
   X-Y
```

Rebase after picking all commits and moving D after A:

```
A-D-X-Y-B-C
```

Rebase after dropping X and Y, and moving D after A:

```
A-D-B-C
```

How can I keep the branch in my history?
Is rebase the wrong tool here?
I have looked at cherry-pick,
but I am not sure how I would use it to achieve the desired outcome.

In case it matters,
the branch did not origin from master,
but from an unrelated repo.
It added a couple of new files
while retaining their commit history from the previous repo.
This is for a local repo
where I am the only contributor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to do something like this:

```
git rebase -i --rebase-merges A
```

The rebase todo instructions will initially look like this

```
label onto

# Branch branch-name/master
reset [new root]
pick X
pick Y
label branch-name/master

reset onto
merge -C pick B
pick C
pick D
```

Reorder the bottom part as in a standard rebase:

```
reset onto
pick D
merge -C pick B
pick C
```

By adding `--rebase-merges`, you are asking Git to try to recreate any existing branches and maintain the merge structure when the rebase takes place.

From the [man pages](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---rebase-mergesrebase-cousinsno-rebase-cousins):

> --rebase-merges[=(rebase-cousins|no-rebase-cousins)]
>
> By default, a rebase will simply drop merge commits from
>   the todo list, and put the rebased commits into a single, linear
>   branch. With `--rebase-merges`, the rebase will instead try
>   to preserve the branching structure within the commits that are to be
>   rebased, by recreating the merge commits. Any resolved merge conflicts
>   or manual amendments in these merge commits will have to be
>   resolved/re-applied manually.
>
> By
>   default, or when `no-rebase-cousins` was specified, commits
>   which do not have `<upstream>` as direct ancestor
>   will keep their original branch point, i.e. commits that would be
>   excluded by [git-log[2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50555740/2166823)](/docs/git-log)'s
>   `--ancestry-path` option will keep their original ancestry
>   by default. If the `rebase-cousins` mode is turned on, such
>   commits are instead rebased onto `<upstream>` (or
>   `<onto>`, if specified).
>
> The `--rebase-merges` mode is similar
>   in spirit to the deprecated `--preserve-merges`, but in
>   contrast to that option works well in interactive rebases: commits can
>   be reordered, inserted and dropped at will.
>
> It is currently only possible to recreate the
>   merge commits using the `recursive` merge strategy;
>   Different merge strategies can be used only via explicit `exec
>   git merge -s <strategy> [...]` commands.

See related StackOverflow topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50555740/2166823).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if that can be achieved with a single run of `git rebase -i`. But you can do it like this:

```
git checkout A
git cherry-pick D
git merge Y # this will create kind-of a B', it won't be the same, though cause you brought D before it
git cherry-pick C
```

Then you could consider moving branches around if you liked the results:

```
git branch -f master
git checkout master
```

Comment: I too would have gone for something like this rather than rebasing. Much clearer, seems to me.

Comment: In all honesty, I don't understand why people are so fond of `git rebase -i`. It's very powerful, don't get me wrong, but there are situations when it just isn't the tool for the job.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. So far, no other git command has caused me to go help a coworker as often as this one.