# Git rewriting history with rebase

Tags: git, workflow, rebase

I am currently working on a branch that looks like this

```
--A------B (master)
        / \
----C--D   E--F (feature_branch, HEAD)
```

I've been trying my best to fix it without success :(
`git-rebase <A_SHA1>` doesn't seem to work at all. There are currently only two branches: `master` and `feature_branch`.

Is there even a way to make it look like this?

```
--A------B (master)
   \    / \
    C--D   E--F (feature_branch, HEAD)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that existing commits cannot be changed, so given:

```
...--α--A------B   <-- master
              / \
 ....--γ--C--D   E--F   <-- feature_branch (HEAD)
```

what you'll inevitably get from a rebase is, instead:

```
            C'-D'  E'-F'  <-- feature_branch (HEAD)
           /    \ /
          /___---B'
         //
...--α--A------B   <-- master
              / \
 ....--γ--C--D   E--F   [abandoned]
```

You can then forcibly move `master` to point to `B'` instead of `B` so that you have:

```
            C'-D'  E'-F'  <-- feature_branch (HEAD)
           /    \ /
          /___---B'  <-- master
         //
...--α--A------B
              / \
 ....--γ--C--D   E--F   [abandoned]
```

It's now possible to ignore the presence of `B`, `γ`, `C`, and so on entirely and pretend that `C'` is `C`, for instance.  Note that commit `γ` has become unreachable unless `α` and `γ` are really the same commit.

To achieve this *using* `git rebase`, you will want the somewhat-newfangled `-r` or `--rebase-merges` option:

```
git checkout feature_branch   # if needed - you've drawn a detached HEAD
git rebase -i -r --onto master <hash-of-γ>
```

after which you will need to delete commits such as `α` and `A` from the list of commits to be `pick`-ed, as these commits are all currently on `feature_branch` as well as on `master`, through merge commit `B`.  (Note that `-r` was new in Git 2.18.  The `-r` option uses the interactive machinery to instruct Git to *re-perform* merges, which is what we will do below.)

Overall, though, it's probably easier to achieve this using separate `git cherry-pick` and `git merge` commands:

```
git checkout --detach <hash-of-A>    # note: master~1 probably finds commit A
git cherry-pick <hash-of-C>          # make C'
git cherry-pick <hash-of-D>          # make D'
git merge --no-ff <hash-of-A>        # make new merge B'
git branch -f master HEAD            # forcibly update master now
git cherry-pick feature_branch~2     # make E'
git cherry-pick feature_branch~1     # make F'
git checkout -B feature_branch       # forcibly move feature_branch and re-attach HEAD
```

If `master~1` does identify commit `A`, you can use that in place of each literal hash here, and in that case, `master^2^` will identify commit `C` and `master^2` will identify commit `D`, so you can use that in place of those two literal hash IDs.

Comment: Not so "newfangled " anymore indeed: `--rebase-merges` comes from [Git 2.18 (Q2 2018)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50555740/6309), and the legacy option it replaces, `--preserve-merge`, was officially deprecated with Git 2.22, Q2 2019.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :) I ended up using `--rebase-merges`.