# Rebasing in git

Tags: git, rebase

I have a question regarding `git rebase`.

I have my main branch - call it `dev`.
I have created a branch from dev  -  call it `myTest`.
i have created another branch from `myTest` - call it `myTest/myTestPart1`

```
----------+------------------- dev
            \
              --------+-------- myTest
                        \
                          ------- myTest/myTestPart1
```

When someone push something to `dev` I do

```
git checkout dev
git pull
```

then I do

```
git checkout myTest
git rebase dev
git push -f
```

then I do

```
git checkout myTest/myTestPart1
git rebase myTest
git push -f
```

Today another developer was working with me and he said I needed to do

```
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/dev
```

What is the difference between what i was doing and what he said to me?

Thank you

Comment: Maybe this question/answer can better clarify https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357122/what-is-the-difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch-git-rebase

Comment: Since you have sub-branches (`myTestPart1` that is based off of `myTest`), if you rebase `myTest` you'll need to do a fancy rebase to keep `myTestPart1` up to date. See the second half of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69303822/184546) for one way to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One difference is that he uses sentences that start with a capital letter and end with a period, and you don't. :)

What he's saying is that you're wasting a lot of effort and time and Internet bandwidth. You don't need to checkout `dev` and pull it in order to rebase onto it. And since you don't need to checkout `dev`, you don't need to swith to `myTest` — because you are already on it.

The way to rebase `myTest` onto latest version of `dev` is to stay on `mytest` and say

```
git fetch origin
git rebase origin/dev
```

You have to admit that's a lot shorter than what you're doing.

Comment: So i can do
git fetch origin in my branch myTest
and then git rebase prigin/dev

should i do the same with myTest/myTest1Part1 or from the first step itself my branch will be already updated.
The dev made git fetch origin in the branch myTest/myTestPart1

thank you

Comment: OK, that is a really good question. No, if you rebase `myTest` that has no effect on `myTestPart1` that branches from it. Let me ask you this: has `myTest` grown since you branched from it, or does `myTestPart1` carry on from the end of `myTest`?

Comment: It grows as i have other branches linked to myTest. Once the linked branches are approved they are merged in myTest. I create myTest/myTestPart2 for example so when approved it will be merged in myTest.

Comment: Well, having rebased MyTest, you'd need to rebase the relevant part of MyTestPart1 onto that. But what you're doing is not a sensible way to work.

Comment: Actually its like a feature. All the tests concerning the festure is in one folder. There is only dev-myTest-myTest/myTestPart1 no more than that.

Comment: After doing git fetch origin and git rebase origin/dev on myTest. I should do git fetch myTest and git rebase origin/myTest on myTest/myTestPart1?

Comment: I'm with you in spirit, but feature branches need to be independent of one another.

Comment: However, I've done my best to answer the question you actually asked, which is what your friend meant and why it's different from what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

The fetch command is mandatory if you want to be sure you are working with updated branches. Without this, ... you rebase into a local history of dev that can be a little bit different from yours.

From atlassian documentation:

> In review, git fetch is a primary command used to download contents
> from a remote repository. git fetch is used in conjunction with git
> remote , git branch , git checkout , and git reset to update a local
> repository to the state of a remote.

If you rebase into your local (and not updated) dev you could simply lost some informations and some colleagues updates.

Comment: When i do git pull isn't all the content updated?

Comment: I think @ZombiePie this answer can better explain what happens: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357122/what-is-the-difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch-git-rebase