# how does git rebase -r works under the hood?

Tags: git

I am practicing `git rebase` and I've found out a flag known as `-r` in `git rebase` which as far as I've realized it keeps merged commits and doesn't drop them, the thing I can't figure it out is how does this `git rebase -r` cherry picks its specific commits from `branch` and merges them with `upstream`, for instance we have:

```
head pointing to F

* bfgh894  (master) I
* b9d9a21 Merge
|\
| * 0542684 (test) H
| * 78fg123 G
* | 7474ecd F
|/
* 4d49fcc E
```

command:

```
git rebase G(commit with G message) I ((commit with I message)
```

the result is:

```
 head pointing to master

* bfgh894  (master) I
* b9d9a21 Merge
|\
| * 0542684 (test) H
| * 78fg123 G
* | 7474ecd F
|/
* 4d49fcc E
```

while this input result with `git rebase G I` is:

```
* 0d24ccb (HEAD) I
* 5b89ee1 H
* e494bcb F
| * bfgh894 (master) I
| * b9d9a21 Merge
| |\
| | * 0542684 (test) H
| |/
|/|
* | 78fg123 G
| * 7474ecd F
|/
* 4d49fcc E
```

the result is the same as the input in `git rebase -r` and no new commit is created and only the head is pointing in to master.

I know how plain `git rebase` cherrypicks the commits under the hood but about `git rebase -r` since it is keeping the merged commits and its divergent links so I think the cherrypicking algorithm differs, so I wonder can anybody explain how `git rebase -r` is cherrypicking commits under the hood and connects those commits to `upstream`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What exactly does git's "rebase --preserve-merges" do (and why?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915430/what-exactly-does-gits-rebase-preserve-merges-do-and-why)

Comment: There's also quite a lot of discussion ofhow rebasing merges works in the manual: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_rebasing_merges

Comment: If you use interactive rebase, you can see a number of commands. `pick` is one of them and I think `pick` corresponds to `git cherry-pick`. The command that deals with merge commits is `merge`.

Comment: tnx man, but literally I didn't understand even a single word of approved answer of that question xd @YesThatIsMyName

Comment: I think git scm documention about this specific topic is a little bit ambiguous ...@IMSoP